# Bounded Voronoi Diagram

Tags: computational-geometry

I am trying to compute a Voronoi diagram bounded by a box. In some cases, the points used to compute the diagram form a diagram such that at least two boundary points are within the same polygon. For Example:

```
centres = {{0, 1250}, {4750, 2000}, {-2500, -2500}, {500, 750}};
boundaries = {{10000, 10000}, {-10000, 
    10000}, {-10000, -10000}, {10000, -10000}};
{diagvert, diagval} = BoundedDiagram[boundaries, centres];
```

With the Voronoi diagram:

[image]

This leads to the error:

> BoundedDiagram::notuniq: BoundedDiagram requires that boundary
>   vertices lie in unique Voronoi polygons.

Since I am trying to generalize the scenario, I can't design a specific boundary for the points, and I would like to use a general big enough boundary. Is there any way to allow multiple boundary points within the same polygon? Or perhaps a different approach?

Answer (score 8):

If I understood correctly that bounding box needs to be automated, you can just use this trick:

```
centres = RandomReal[1, {50, 2}];

voronoi = ListDensityPlot[Append[#, 0] & /@ centres, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Black, Frame -> False, ColorFunction -> (White &)]
```

[image]

Then information about Polygons and other geometry is available as

```
Cases[voronoi, _Polygon, Infinity]
```

or

```
voronoi // InputForm
```

or rebuilding

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], 
  GraphicsComplex[voronoi[[1, 1]], Cases[voronoi, _Polygon, Infinity]]}]
```