# Remove noise from data

Tags: data, physics, filtering, signal-processing

[image: Experimental data[1]]

Hi, as you can see above I have some experimental data which has a large offset and shows clear noise fluctations around the tendency of the curve. I wanted to ask if someone could suggest me a method to remove the noise, withoud eliminating the oscillations.

Using EstimateBackground[] I was able to envelope the oscillations (yellow and green curves) but as you can see, the noise spikes make it very uncertain. The red curve was my attempt to reproduce the tendency of the oscillations and smoothing the data, using a median noise filter ([Median noise filter](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116543/filtering-background-with-resonance-or-peaks)), but it is a little off.

[image]

Thanks for your help!

```
data = Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
  Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/7agjd.png"],"Byte"]]]]
```

Comment: You could try applying `MovingAverage` or `TrimmedMean` on the data, together with `BlockMap`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! The MovingAverage methog worked fine, but the result is still not very smooth, even increasing the number of points to be averaged. Could you elaborate on the second method you suggested?

Comment: With `TrimmedMean` you will be able to remove outliers on a given window (defined by, e.g. `BlockMap`) before taking the average. This should be smoother in principle.

Comment: Check this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81121/how-to-remove-outliers-from-data

Comment: I added the data. Thanks, I'll check it out!

Comment: Remove the spike noise: Join[{data[[1]]}, Map[#[[2]] &, Map[If[#[[1]] - #[[2]] > .05, {#[[1]], (#[[1]] + #[[3]])/2, #[[3]]}, #] &,  Partition[data, 3, 1]]], {data[[-1]]}]

Comment: How do you know it's noise? In other words, the answer will depend on how the signal and the noise differ; not all noise is created equal. (In your case, there are a lot of large downward spikes but fewer and smaller downward ones, which marks your noise as different from the standard gaussian model.) Trying to remove the noise from a signal without a good model for its characteristics might make it look prettier, but it won't produce scientifically valuable data if that's what you're after. For the latter, try [stats.se] for how to approach this, then this site can help implement it.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, yes, I am aware that this might not be noise and the fact that its distribution is not totally "white" is something I will investigate further. At this point I am just testing different approaches, and see how my results look without it, but I won't throw this under the rug. Thanks for the kind advice though, I will definitely check the linked site out!

Comment: what is the underlying process?

Comment: In order not to reinvent the wheel, check please http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37380/savitzky-golay-filter-to-smooth-noisy-data . Savitzky-Golay Filter works excellent !

Comment: I think the question is more about removing outliers. In general for this kind data of data I would suggest using [Quantile Regression](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2014/01/01/quantile-regression-with-b-splines/) for analysis and other tasks (outliers removal included).

Comment: I'd look into Gaussian Processes. They are a very powerful tool for denoising.

Comment: @Davidmh: IIRC, Gaussian Processes are linear, like the Savitzky Golay filter. So they're not robust to extremely heavy-tailed noise as this data contains, right? At least not without preprocessing to remove the worst outliers first.

Comment: @nikie I have just tested it, and it definitely ignores them. You are right that sufficiently extreme outliers will ruin the results, but they are fairly robust. If you are in this extreme case, you can adjust the priors to account for the fat distribution of residuals or use a heteroscedastic regression to learn which points to ignore.

Comment: At first glance I'd suggest a `MovingAverage`. But yu could also try `WienerFilter`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could try [`BilateralFilter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BilateralFilter.html):

```
ListLinePlot[{data, 
  BilateralFilter[data, 2, .5, MaxIterations -> 25]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thin, Red}]
```

[image]

Or alternatively, [`MeanShiftFilter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeanShiftFilter.html) can produce similar results:

```
ListLinePlot[{data, 
  MeanShiftFilter[data, 5, .5, MaxIterations -> 10]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thin, Red}]
```

[image]

Third alternative, as mentioned by @Xavier in the comments, is to apply [`TrimmedMean`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrimmedMean.html) over a sliding window:

```
ListLinePlot[{data, ArrayFilter[TrimmedMean, data, 20]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thin, Red}]
```

[image]

As requested in the comments, a Savitzky Golay filter:

```
ListLinePlot[{
  data,
  ListConvolve[SavitzkyGolayMatrix[{10}, 2], 
   ArrayPad[data, 10, "Fixed"]]
  }, PlotStyle -> {Thin, Red}]
```

[image]

For comparison:

```
Show[
 ListPlot[data, PlotLegends -> {"Raw Data"}],
 ListLinePlot[{BilateralFilter[data, 2, .5, MaxIterations -> 25], 
   MeanShiftFilter[data, 5, .5, MaxIterations -> 10], 
   ArrayFilter[TrimmedMean, data, 20], 
   ListConvolve[SavitzkyGolayMatrix[{10}, 2], 
    ArrayPad[data, 10, "Fixed"]]},
  PlotLegends -> {"BilateralFilter", "MeanShiftFilter", 
    "ArrayFilter[TrimmedMean]", "SavitzkyGolay"}], ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

- `MeanShiftFilter` and `BilateralFilter` produce a smooth result, and are almost indistinguishable with these parameters.
- The sliding window `TrimmedMean` filter technique looks more "ragged" in comparison.
- I couldn't get a smooth curve with the Savitzky Golay filter, probably because the large outliers aren't well suited to linear filtering.

You'll have to play with the parameters to each of them to get the results you want.

Comment: I would recommend using the same parameters for the BilateralFilter. It's a bit confusing seeing it behave one way in the first plot and another way in the combined plot.

Comment: Would be interesting to compare your results with that of the Savitzky-Golay filter (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37380/savitzky-golay-filter-to-smooth-noisy-data)

Comment: Very pedagogical answer.

Answer (score 20):

I would suggest using a median filter with small radius to eliminate the large spikes, then a mean filter to smooth the remaining signal. @Xavier essentially combines these two filters by using `TrimmedMean`.

Other than the large spikes, your data seem to have a strong signal with a period of about 10 points. You could use `BandstopFilter` to remove this, or `LowpassFilter` to eliminate this oscillation plus higher frequencies.

In the following, I removed the mean from your original data.

```
Manipulate[
   Module[{f},
      f = LowpassFilter[MedianFilter[data, r], w];
      ListLinePlot[{data, f - Mean[f]}, ImageSize -> 600, Frame -> True, 
                   PlotStyle -> {Thin, Thick}]
   ],
   {{r, 0, "Median Filter Radius"}, 0, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
   {{w, 3., "Cutoff Angular Frequency"}, 0.002,Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: median and lowpass filter]

Answer (score 12):

I am not sure what is called "noise" in the question, from the description, I think it is about removing outliers. This solution uses [Quantile regression](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2014/01/01/quantile-regression-with-b-splines/) twice: to detect the outliers, and then to find quantile regression curves in the data without the outliers.

Load the package:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/QuantileRegression.m"]
```

Adding x-coordinates to the data:

```
data = Transpose[{Range[Length[data]], data}];
```

Selection of quantiles to detect the outliers:

```
qs = {0.05, 0.5, 0.98};
{qs[[1]], 1 - qs[[-1]]}*Length[data]
(* {25.6, 10.24} *)
```

Quantile regression with the selected quantiles:

```
qfuncs = QuantileRegression[data, 15, qs];
```

Finding the top outliers:

```
topOutliers = Select[data, qfuncs[[-1]][#[[1]]] < #[[2]] &]

(* {{54, 8.16422}, {145, 8.16422}, {155, 8.14875}, {203, 
  8.19841}, {289, 8.14254}, {370, 8.17358}, {433, 8.17358}} *)
```

Finding the bottom outliers:

```
bottomOutliers = Select[data, qfuncs[[1]][#[[1]]] > #[[2]] &]

(* {{29, 7.9156}, {78, 8.08349}, {81, 7.98714}, {101, 
  8.03685}, {127, 7.99335}, {140, 8.01821}, {178, 7.8689}, {182, 
  8.07728}, {220, 8.08349}, {263, 7.98714}, {268, 8.00884}, {323, 
  8.12381}, {331, 8.12696}, {334, 8.09276}, {386, 8.0617}, {387, 
  8.05243}, {406, 8.08349}, {454, 8.0617}, {456, 8.05864}, {486, 
  8.07412}, {496, 8.10833}} *)
```

Plot data, regression quantiles, and outliers:

```
qfPlot = ListLinePlot[
   Table[{#, qfuncs[[i]][#]} & /@ 
     Rescale[Range[0, 1, 0.005], {0, 1}, MinMax[data[[All, 1]]]], {i, 
     1, Length[qfuncs]}], PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotLegends -> qs];
Show[{ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.5]}, 
   PlotTheme -> "Detailed"], qfPlot, 
  ListPlot[{topOutliers, bottomOutliers}, PlotStyle -> {{
      Blue, PointSize[0.01]}, {Red, PointSize[0.01]}}]}, 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Remove the outliers from the data:

```
newData = Complement[data, Join[topOutliers, bottomOutliers]];
```

Make another quantile regression computation over the new data. (This time is to facilitate analysis instead of detecting outliers.)

```
Block[{data = newData, qfuncs, qs = {0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95}},
 qfuncs = QuantileRegression[data, 40, qs]; 
 Show[{ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> GrayLevel[0.5], PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotTheme -> "Detailed"], 
   ListLinePlot[
    Transpose@
     Map[Thread[{#, Through[qfuncs[#]]}] &, 
      Rescale[Range[0, 1, 0.005], {0, 1}, MinMax[data[[All, 1]]]]], 
    PlotStyle -> Map[If[# == 0.5, Thick, Thin] &, qs], 
    PlotLegends -> qs]}, ImageSize -> 600]]
```

[image]

Obviously other methods of signal analysis can be applied to the cleaned data. In this particular case, the cleaned data would give better results for the conditional PDF/CDF reconstruction shown in this blog post ["Estimation of conditional density distributions"](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2014/01/13/estimation-of-conditional-density-distributions/).

Comment: For computing the average of a dataset the $q=0.5$ quantile (i.e. the median) is already resistant to outliers (e.g. the median of $\{1,2,3,4,500\}$ is still $3$). Is this no longer true in the case of computing regression curves? What happens if you only run quantile regression once without removing outliers first?

Comment: Of course [QR is robust](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2013/12/23/quantile-regression-robustness/) -- it is its major feature. The point of my answer is more about the application of Quantile Regression to remove outliers.

Comment: Thanks, the QR worked very fine. How can I apply the same method to an image (2 coordinates dimension + 1 intensity dimension) instead of a line (1 coordinate dimension + 1 dimension intensity) like this example?

Comment: @Filipe It depends what you want do with your 3D data and how it is structured. If you want to remove 3D outliers please see [this MSE answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114032/34008) or this blog post ["Finding outliers in 2D and 3D numerical data"](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2016/04/30/finding-outliers-in-2d-and-3d-numerical-data/). If you want to do fitting and your data is over a regular grid, then you can apply QR along each X and Y grid line.

Comment: @Filipe I did not read carefully your comment -- I missed the "image" part/interpretation. Consider posting a new MSE question. I think some modification of [this answer of "Cluster a signal into areas of equal intensity"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105889/34008) can be applied.