# Smoothing noisy data

Tags: filtering, smoothing

I have this data shown in picture 1 below and I want to filter it. I tried some filters but I couldn't get good results. seems that I didn't choose the best parameters for it.

[image: noisy data]

I want to smooth my data (in blue) to be closer to the one in red (without using the data of the red curve.) I appreciate any help.

[image: after smoothing]

---

This is the list I am using in a CSV file (sorry I am a new user in StackExchange and don't know how to upload CSV file here)

```
data={{-0.198,-0.0934245},{-0.196,-0.17041},{-0.194,-0.0829264},{-0.192,0.134033},{-0.19,0.134033},{-0.188,-0.110921},{-0.186,-0.156413},{-0.184,-0.0479329},{-0.182,0.172526},{-0.18,0.0605469},{-0.178,-0.00244141},{-0.176,0.00105794},{-0.174,-0.128418},{-0.172,-0.058431},{-0.17,-0.068929},{-0.168,0.0955404},{-0.166,0.120036},{-0.164,0.20402},{-0.162,0.0570475},{-0.16,0.0990397},{-0.158,0.270508},{-0.156,-0.0759277},{-0.154,0.158529},{-0.152,0.144531},{-0.15,0.253011},{-0.148,0.15153},{-0.146,0.315999},{-0.144,0.291504},{-0.142,0.214518},{-0.14,0.169027},{-0.138,0.25651},{-0.136,0.176025},{-0.134,0.232015},{-0.132,0.197021},{-0.13,0.081543},{-0.128,0.00105794},{-0.126,0.221517},{-0.124,0.0780436},{-0.122,0.214518},{-0.12,0.190023},{-0.118,0.413981},{-0.116,0.134033},{-0.114,0.211019},{-0.112,0.0955404},{-0.11,0.123535},{-0.108,0.0745443},{-0.106,0.228516},{-0.104,0.162028},{-0.102,0.162028},{-0.1,-0.0409342},{-0.098,0.190023},{-0.096,0.158529},{-0.094,0.295003},{-0.092,0.315999},{-0.09,0.270508},{-0.088,0.197021},{-0.086,0.281006},{-0.084,0.25651},{-0.082,0.158529},{-0.08,0.20752},{-0.078,0.281006},{-0.076,0.322998},{-0.074,0.239014},{-0.072,0.148031},{-0.07,0.424479},{-0.068,0.281006},{-0.066,0.295003},{-0.064,0.270508},{-0.062,0.130534},{-0.06,0.459473},{-0.058,0.36499},{-0.056,0.242513},{-0.054,0.113037},{-0.052,0.438477},{-0.05,0.165527},{-0.048,0.281006},{-0.046,0.148031},{-0.044,0.267008},{-0.042,0.155029},{-0.04,0.274007},{-0.038,0.315999},{-0.036,0.445475},{-0.034,0.109538},{-0.032,0.20752},{-0.03,0.319499},{-0.028,0.218018},{-0.026,0.158529},{-0.024,0.20752},{-0.022,0.221517},{-0.02,0.158529},{-0.018,0.291504},{-0.016,0.25651},{-0.014,0.25651},{-0.012,0.281006},{-0.01,0.441976},{-0.008,0.106038},{-0.006,0.214518},{-0.004,0.354492},{-0.002,0.288005},{1.53*10^-16,0.274007},{0.002,0.197021},{0.004,0.200521},{0.006,0.092041},{0.008,0.232015},{0.01,0.347493},{0.012,0.249512},{0.014,0.497965},{0.016,0.406982},{0.018,0.193522},{0.02,0.291504},{0.022,0.288005},{0.024,0.232015},{0.026,0.169027},{0.028,0.424479},{0.03,0.081543},{0.032,0.249512},{0.034,0.378988},{0.036,0.221517},{0.038,0.253011},{0.04,0.336995},{0.042,0.483968},{0.044,0.424479},{0.046,0.336995},{0.048,0.47347},{0.05,0.375488},{0.052,0.42098},{0.054,0.42098},{0.056,0.357992},{0.058,0.378988},{0.06,0.476969},{0.062,0.235514},{0.064,0.340495},{0.066,0.396484},{0.068,0.357992},{0.07,0.490967},{0.072,0.263509},{0.074,0.263509},{0.076,0.225016},{0.078,0.36499},{0.08,0.267008},{0.082,0.179525},{0.084,0.211019},{0.086,0.382487},{0.088,0.340495},{0.09,0.319499},{0.092,0.459473},{0.094,0.288005},{0.096,0.350993},{0.098,0.116536},{0.1,0.309001},{0.102,0.277507},{0.104,0.497965},{0.106,0.36499},{0.108,0.225016},{0.11,0.134033},{0.112,0.315999},{0.114,0.47347},{0.116,0.336995},{0.118,0.448975},{0.12,0.281006},{0.122,0.298503},{0.124,0.410482},{0.126,0.3125},{0.128,0.336995},{0.13,0.403483},{0.132,0.326497},{0.134,0.399984},{0.136,0.36849},{0.138,0.560954},{0.14,0.522461},{0.142,0.221517},{0.144,0.494466},{0.146,0.385986},{0.148,0.326497},{0.15,0.291504},{0.152,0.26001},{0.154,0.309001},{0.156,0.36499},{0.158,0.455973},{0.16,0.455973},{0.162,0.378988},{0.164,0.41748},{0.166,0.225016},{0.168,0.183024},{0.17,0.26001},{0.172,0.63444},{0.174,0.176025},{0.176,0.455973},{0.178,0.267008},{0.18,0.396484},{0.182,0.504964},{0.184,0.277507},{0.186,0.246012},{0.188,0.427979},{0.19,0.543457},{0.192,0.518962},{0.194,0.511963},{0.196,0.295003},{0.198,0.511963},{0.2,0.613444},{0.202,0.487467},{0.204,0.263509},{0.206,0.36499},{0.208,0.357992},{0.21,0.242513},{0.212,0.211019},{0.214,0.431478},{0.216,0.354492},{0.218,0.431478},{0.22,0.466471},{0.222,0.406982},{0.224,0.350993},{0.226,0.560954},{0.228,0.389486},{0.23,0.52946},{0.232,0.550456},{0.234,0.267008},{0.236,0.518962},{0.238,0.515462},{0.24,0.42098},{0.242,0.550456},{0.244,0.350993},{0.246,0.522461},{0.248,0.424479},{0.25,0.424479},{0.252,0.284505},{0.254,0.63444},{0.256,0.637939},{0.258,0.326497},{0.26,0.585449},{0.262,0.375488},{0.264,0.515462},{0.266,0.406982},{0.268,0.466471},{0.27,0.487467},{0.272,0.560954},{0.274,0.47347},{0.276,0.438477},{0.278,0.543457},{0.28,0.424479},{0.282,0.721924},{0.284,0.396484},{0.286,0.434977},{0.288,0.553955},{0.29,0.518962},{0.292,0.644938},{0.294,0.63444},{0.296,0.438477},{0.298,0.47347},{0.3,0.679932},{0.302,0.522461},{0.304,0.487467},{0.306,0.900391},{0.308,0.616943},{0.31,0.539958},{0.312,0.462972},{0.314,0.648438},{0.316,0.543457},{0.318,0.756917},{0.32,0.683431},{0.322,0.697428},{0.324,0.781413},{0.326,0.79541},{0.328,0.900391},{0.33,0.69043},{0.332,0.819906},{0.334,0.718424},{0.336,0.739421},{0.338,0.714925},{0.34,0.714925},{0.342,0.753418},{0.344,0.721924},{0.346,0.854899},{0.348,0.74292},{0.35,1.03687},{0.352,1.01237},{0.354,0.942383},{0.356,1.07886},{0.358,0.8479},{0.36,0.942383},{0.362,1.01587},{0.364,0.721924},{0.366,1.07886},{0.368,0.882894},{0.37,0.840902},{0.372,0.987874},{0.374,0.970378},{0.376,0.924886},{0.378,0.910889},{0.38,0.8514},{0.382,0.935384},{0.384,1.11385},{0.386,1.05786},{0.388,1.10685},{0.39,1.16634},{0.392,0.700928},{0.394,1.16634},{0.396,1.21883},{0.398,1.12085},{0.4,1.05436},{0.398,1.31681},{0.396,1.12435},{0.394,1.00887},{0.392,1.14884},{0.39,1.56527},{0.388,0.693929},{0.386,0.483968},{0.384,0.186523},{0.382,0.410482},{0.38,0.211019},{0.378,0.295003},{0.376,0.343994},{0.374,0.20752},{0.372,-0.0164388},{0.37,0.357992},{0.368,0.357992},{0.366,0.0255534},{0.364,-0.0199382},{0.362,-0.00594076},{0.36,0.0605469},{0.358,-0.212402},{0.356,-0.0479329},{0.354,-0.058431},{0.352,-0.289388},{0.35,-0.0199382},{0.348,-0.292887},{0.346,-0.191406},{0.344,-0.310384},{0.342,-0.166911},{0.34,-0.348877},{0.338,-0.282389},{0.336,-0.0444336},{0.334,-0.380371},{0.332,-0.289388},{0.33,-0.166911},{0.328,-0.471354},{0.326,-0.33488},{0.324,-0.38737},{0.322,-0.250895},{0.32,-0.271891},{0.318,-0.205404},{0.316,-0.446859},{0.314,-0.390869},{0.312,-0.299886},{0.31,-0.33488},{0.308,-0.341878},{0.306,-0.320882},{0.304,-0.418864},{0.302,-0.362874},{0.3,-0.551839},{0.298,-0.625326},{0.296,-0.313883},{0.294,-0.436361},{0.292,-0.436361},{0.29,-0.247396},{0.288,-0.341878},{0.286,-0.149414},{0.284,-0.453857},{0.282,-0.352376},{0.28,-0.296387},{0.278,-0.149414},{0.276,-0.149414},{0.274,-0.0409342},{0.272,-0.27889},{0.27,-0.429362},{0.268,-0.0374349},{0.266,-0.0829264},{0.264,-0.289388},{0.262,-0.607829},{0.26,-0.359375},{0.258,-0.240397},{0.256,-0.194906},{0.254,-0.156413},{0.252,-0.33138},{0.25,-0.488851},{0.248,-0.320882},{0.246,-0.292887},{0.244,-0.394368},{0.242,-0.446859},{0.24,-0.0619303},{0.238,-0.0654297},{0.236,-0.114421},{0.234,-0.509847},{0.232,-0.103923},{0.23,-0.152913},{0.228,-0.128418},{0.226,-0.450358},{0.224,-0.296387},{0.222,-0.268392},{0.22,-0.369873},{0.218,-0.0724284},{0.216,-0.219401},{0.214,-0.264893},{0.212,-0.285889},{0.21,-0.348877},{0.208,-0.485352},{0.206,-0.219401},{0.204,-0.0864258},{0.202,-0.282389},{0.2,-0.366374},{0.198,-0.443359},{0.196,-0.180908},{0.194,-0.159912},{0.192,-0.310384},{0.19,-0.460856},{0.188,-0.247396},{0.186,-0.27889},{0.184,-0.27889},{0.182,-0.516846},{0.18,-0.366374},{0.178,-0.285889},{0.176,-0.296387},{0.174,-0.166911},{0.172,-0.264893},{0.17,-0.285889},{0.168,-0.33488},{0.166,-0.229899},{0.164,-0.303385},{0.162,-0.268392},{0.16,-0.156413},{0.158,-0.390869},{0.156,-0.341878},{0.154,-0.159912},{0.152,-0.397868},{0.15,-0.236898},{0.148,-0.394368},{0.146,-0.33138},{0.144,-0.348877},{0.142,-0.369873},{0.14,-0.17041},{0.138,-0.394368},{0.136,-0.338379},{0.134,-0.268392},{0.132,-0.306885},{0.13,-0.2229},{0.128,-0.275391},{0.126,-0.299886},{0.124,-0.247396},{0.122,-0.327881},{0.12,-0.418864},{0.118,-0.394368},{0.116,-0.156413},{0.114,-0.380371},{0.112,-0.352376},{0.11,-0.135417},{0.108,-0.397868},{0.106,-0.404867},{0.104,-0.397868},{0.102,-0.33138},{0.1,-0.17391},{0.098,-0.345378},{0.096,-0.348877},{0.094,-0.348877},{0.092,-0.355876},{0.09,-0.366374},{0.088,-0.436361},{0.086,-0.359375},{0.084,-0.292887},{0.082,-0.380371},{0.08,-0.534342},{0.078,-0.285889},{0.076,-0.33138},{0.074,-0.327881},{0.072,-0.180908},{0.07,-0.268392},{0.068,-0.310384},{0.066,-0.352376},{0.064,-0.436361},{0.062,-0.229899},{0.06,-0.292887},{0.058,-0.338379},{0.056,-0.373372},{0.054,-0.513346},{0.052,-0.338379},{0.05,-0.240397},{0.048,-0.275391},{0.046,-0.513346},{0.044,-0.446859},{0.042,-0.338379},{0.04,-0.268392},{0.038,-0.320882},{0.036,-0.219401},{0.034,-0.432861},{0.032,-0.317383},{0.03,-0.376872},{0.028,-0.471354},{0.026,-0.345378},{0.024,-0.366374},{0.022,-0.401367},{0.02,-0.527344},{0.018,-0.485352},{0.016,-0.271891},{0.014,-0.27889},{0.012,-0.453857},{0.01,-0.527344},{0.008,-0.366374},{0.006,-0.366374},{0.004,-0.194906},{0.002,-0.369873},{1.25*10^-16,-0.485352},{-0.002,-0.597331},{-0.004,-0.338379},{-0.006,-0.380371},{-0.008,-0.394368},{-0.01,-0.443359},{-0.012,-0.285889},{-0.014,-0.436361},{-0.016,-0.516846},{-0.018,-0.418864},{-0.02,-0.338379},{-0.022,-0.320882},{-0.024,-0.317383},{-0.026,-0.33488},{-0.028,-0.327881},{-0.03,-0.2264},{-0.032,-0.317383},{-0.034,-0.359375},{-0.036,-0.38387},{-0.038,-0.576335},{-0.04,-0.677816},{-0.042,-0.418864},{-0.044,-0.558838},{-0.046,-0.450358},{-0.048,-0.499349},{-0.05,-0.352376},{-0.052,-0.527344},{-0.054,-0.159912},{-0.056,-0.523844},{-0.058,-0.257894},{-0.06,-0.460856},{-0.062,-0.369873},{-0.064,-0.397868},{-0.066,-0.614827},{-0.068,-0.516846},{-0.07,-0.257894},{-0.072,-0.558838},{-0.074,-0.415365},{-0.076,-0.730306},{-0.078,-0.296387},{-0.08,-0.523844},{-0.082,-0.49585},{-0.084,-0.502848},{-0.086,-0.562337},{-0.088,-0.562337},{-0.09,-0.310384},{-0.092,-0.373372},{-0.094,-0.373372},{-0.096,-0.320882},{-0.098,-0.380371},{-0.1,-0.530843},{-0.102,-0.397868},{-0.104,-0.572835},{-0.106,-0.516846},{-0.108,-0.408366},{-0.11,-0.380371},{-0.112,-0.527344},{-0.114,-0.478353},{-0.116,-0.579834},{-0.118,-0.425863},{-0.12,-0.310384},{-0.122,-0.457357},{-0.124,-0.520345},{-0.126,-0.338379},{-0.128,-0.27889},{-0.13,-0.579834},{-0.132,-0.555339},{-0.134,-0.593831},{-0.136,-0.541341},{-0.138,-0.464355},{-0.14,-0.534342},{-0.142,-0.450358},{-0.144,-0.432861},{-0.146,-0.366374},{-0.148,-0.478353},{-0.15,-0.443359},{-0.152,-0.488851},{-0.154,-0.681315},{-0.156,-0.635824},{-0.158,-0.345378},{-0.16,-0.49585},{-0.162,-0.597331},{-0.164,-0.502848},{-0.166,-0.485352},{-0.168,-0.621826},{-0.17,-0.516846},{-0.172,-0.625326},{-0.174,-0.572835},{-0.176,-0.478353},{-0.178,-0.569336},{-0.18,-0.569336},{-0.182,-0.569336},{-0.184,-0.712809},{-0.186,-0.723307},{-0.188,-0.569336},{-0.19,-0.586833},{-0.192,-0.604329},{-0.194,-0.674316},{-0.196,-0.688314},{-0.198,-0.614827},{-0.2,-0.747803}
};
```

---

I used this code and tried to change the parameters but couldn't get the right ones for a smooth curve.

```
ListLinePlot[{data, 
 BilateralFilter[data, 2, .14, MaxIterations -> 5]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thin, Red}]
```

I tried to follow this example:
 [Remove noise from data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124928/remove-noise-from-data?newreg=e0bd1515ef4b4b0a8eb30b316da8f2a2)
 How can we choose the right parameters?
Thanks,

Comment: Whatever your data, I'd suggest looking at https://reference.wolframcloud.com/language/guide/LinearAndNonlinearFilters.html - possibly first converting your data to `TimeSeries`.

Comment: Thanks for providing data, what about the code that failed you?

Comment: Is the noise vertical, or should both dimensions be treated as noisy?

Comment: yes the noise is actually vertical

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An approach using [`FindFormula`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFormula.html)

```
data = {{-0.198, -0.0934245}, {-0.196, -0.17041}, {-0.194, -0.0829264}, \
{-0.192, 0.134033}, {-0.19, 
    0.134033}, {-0.188, -0.110921}, {-0.186, -0.156413}, {-0.184, \
-0.0479329}, {-0.182, 0.172526}, {-0.18, 
    0.0605469}, {-0.178, -0.00244141}, {-0.176, 
    0.00105794}, {-0.174, -0.128418}, {-0.172, -0.058431}, {-0.17, \
-0.068929}, {-0.168, 0.0955404}, {-0.166, 0.120036}, {-0.164, 
    0.20402}, {-0.162, 0.0570475}, {-0.16, 0.0990397}, {-0.158, 
    0.270508}, {-0.156, -0.0759277}, {-0.154, 0.158529}, {-0.152, 
    0.144531}, {-0.15, 0.253011}, {-0.148, 0.15153}, {-0.146, 
    0.315999}, {-0.144, 0.291504}, {-0.142, 0.214518}, {-0.14, 
    0.169027}, {-0.138, 0.25651}, {-0.136, 0.176025}, {-0.134, 
    0.232015}, {-0.132, 0.197021}, {-0.13, 0.081543}, {-0.128, 
    0.00105794}, {-0.126, 0.221517}, {-0.124, 0.0780436}, {-0.122, 
    0.214518}, {-0.12, 0.190023}, {-0.118, 0.413981}, {-0.116, 
    0.134033}, {-0.114, 0.211019}, {-0.112, 0.0955404}, {-0.11, 
    0.123535}, {-0.108, 0.0745443}, {-0.106, 0.228516}, {-0.104, 
    0.162028}, {-0.102, 0.162028}, {-0.1, -0.0409342}, {-0.098, 
    0.190023}, {-0.096, 0.158529}, {-0.094, 0.295003}, {-0.092, 
    0.315999}, {-0.09, 0.270508}, {-0.088, 0.197021}, {-0.086, 
    0.281006}, {-0.084, 0.25651}, {-0.082, 0.158529}, {-0.08, 
    0.20752}, {-0.078, 0.281006}, {-0.076, 0.322998}, {-0.074, 
    0.239014}, {-0.072, 0.148031}, {-0.07, 0.424479}, {-0.068, 
    0.281006}, {-0.066, 0.295003}, {-0.064, 0.270508}, {-0.062, 
    0.130534}, {-0.06, 0.459473}, {-0.058, 0.36499}, {-0.056, 
    0.242513}, {-0.054, 0.113037}, {-0.052, 0.438477}, {-0.05, 
    0.165527}, {-0.048, 0.281006}, {-0.046, 0.148031}, {-0.044, 
    0.267008}, {-0.042, 0.155029}, {-0.04, 0.274007}, {-0.038, 
    0.315999}, {-0.036, 0.445475}, {-0.034, 0.109538}, {-0.032, 
    0.20752}, {-0.03, 0.319499}, {-0.028, 0.218018}, {-0.026, 
    0.158529}, {-0.024, 0.20752}, {-0.022, 0.221517}, {-0.02, 
    0.158529}, {-0.018, 0.291504}, {-0.016, 0.25651}, {-0.014, 
    0.25651}, {-0.012, 0.281006}, {-0.01, 0.441976}, {-0.008, 
    0.106038}, {-0.006, 0.214518}, {-0.004, 0.354492}, {-0.002, 
    0.288005}, {1.53*10^-16, 0.274007}, {0.002, 0.197021}, {0.004, 
    0.200521}, {0.006, 0.092041}, {0.008, 0.232015}, {0.01, 0.347493}, {0.012,
     0.249512}, {0.014, 0.497965}, {0.016, 0.406982}, {0.018, 
    0.193522}, {0.02, 0.291504}, {0.022, 0.288005}, {0.024, 0.232015}, {0.026,
     0.169027}, {0.028, 0.424479}, {0.03, 0.081543}, {0.032, 
    0.249512}, {0.034, 0.378988}, {0.036, 0.221517}, {0.038, 0.253011}, {0.04,
     0.336995}, {0.042, 0.483968}, {0.044, 0.424479}, {0.046, 
    0.336995}, {0.048, 0.47347}, {0.05, 0.375488}, {0.052, 0.42098}, {0.054, 
    0.42098}, {0.056, 0.357992}, {0.058, 0.378988}, {0.06, 0.476969}, {0.062, 
    0.235514}, {0.064, 0.340495}, {0.066, 0.396484}, {0.068, 0.357992}, {0.07,
     0.490967}, {0.072, 0.263509}, {0.074, 0.263509}, {0.076, 
    0.225016}, {0.078, 0.36499}, {0.08, 0.267008}, {0.082, 0.179525}, {0.084, 
    0.211019}, {0.086, 0.382487}, {0.088, 0.340495}, {0.09, 0.319499}, {0.092,
     0.459473}, {0.094, 0.288005}, {0.096, 0.350993}, {0.098, 0.116536}, {0.1,
     0.309001}, {0.102, 0.277507}, {0.104, 0.497965}, {0.106, 
    0.36499}, {0.108, 0.225016}, {0.11, 0.134033}, {0.112, 0.315999}, {0.114, 
    0.47347}, {0.116, 0.336995}, {0.118, 0.448975}, {0.12, 0.281006}, {0.122, 
    0.298503}, {0.124, 0.410482}, {0.126, 0.3125}, {0.128, 0.336995}, {0.13, 
    0.403483}, {0.132, 0.326497}, {0.134, 0.399984}, {0.136, 0.36849}, {0.138,
     0.560954}, {0.14, 0.522461}, {0.142, 0.221517}, {0.144, 
    0.494466}, {0.146, 0.385986}, {0.148, 0.326497}, {0.15, 0.291504}, {0.152,
     0.26001}, {0.154, 0.309001}, {0.156, 0.36499}, {0.158, 0.455973}, {0.16, 
    0.455973}, {0.162, 0.378988}, {0.164, 0.41748}, {0.166, 0.225016}, {0.168,
     0.183024}, {0.17, 0.26001}, {0.172, 0.63444}, {0.174, 0.176025}, {0.176, 
    0.455973}, {0.178, 0.267008}, {0.18, 0.396484}, {0.182, 0.504964}, {0.184,
     0.277507}, {0.186, 0.246012}, {0.188, 0.427979}, {0.19, 
    0.543457}, {0.192, 0.518962}, {0.194, 0.511963}, {0.196, 
    0.295003}, {0.198, 0.511963}, {0.2, 0.613444}, {0.202, 0.487467}, {0.204, 
    0.263509}, {0.206, 0.36499}, {0.208, 0.357992}, {0.21, 0.242513}, {0.212, 
    0.211019}, {0.214, 0.431478}, {0.216, 0.354492}, {0.218, 0.431478}, {0.22,
     0.466471}, {0.222, 0.406982}, {0.224, 0.350993}, {0.226, 
    0.560954}, {0.228, 0.389486}, {0.23, 0.52946}, {0.232, 0.550456}, {0.234, 
    0.267008}, {0.236, 0.518962}, {0.238, 0.515462}, {0.24, 0.42098}, {0.242, 
    0.550456}, {0.244, 0.350993}, {0.246, 0.522461}, {0.248, 0.424479}, {0.25,
     0.424479}, {0.252, 0.284505}, {0.254, 0.63444}, {0.256, 
    0.637939}, {0.258, 0.326497}, {0.26, 0.585449}, {0.262, 0.375488}, {0.264,
     0.515462}, {0.266, 0.406982}, {0.268, 0.466471}, {0.27, 
    0.487467}, {0.272, 0.560954}, {0.274, 0.47347}, {0.276, 0.438477}, {0.278,
     0.543457}, {0.28, 0.424479}, {0.282, 0.721924}, {0.284, 
    0.396484}, {0.286, 0.434977}, {0.288, 0.553955}, {0.29, 0.518962}, {0.292,
     0.644938}, {0.294, 0.63444}, {0.296, 0.438477}, {0.298, 0.47347}, {0.3, 
    0.679932}, {0.302, 0.522461}, {0.304, 0.487467}, {0.306, 
    0.900391}, {0.308, 0.616943}, {0.31, 0.539958}, {0.312, 0.462972}, {0.314,
     0.648438}, {0.316, 0.543457}, {0.318, 0.756917}, {0.32, 
    0.683431}, {0.322, 0.697428}, {0.324, 0.781413}, {0.326, 0.79541}, {0.328,
     0.900391}, {0.33, 0.69043}, {0.332, 0.819906}, {0.334, 0.718424}, {0.336,
     0.739421}, {0.338, 0.714925}, {0.34, 0.714925}, {0.342, 
    0.753418}, {0.344, 0.721924}, {0.346, 0.854899}, {0.348, 0.74292}, {0.35, 
    1.03687}, {0.352, 1.01237}, {0.354, 0.942383}, {0.356, 1.07886}, {0.358, 
    0.8479}, {0.36, 0.942383}, {0.362, 1.01587}, {0.364, 0.721924}, {0.366, 
    1.07886}, {0.368, 0.882894}, {0.37, 0.840902}, {0.372, 0.987874}, {0.374, 
    0.970378}, {0.376, 0.924886}, {0.378, 0.910889}, {0.38, 0.8514}, {0.382, 
    0.935384}, {0.384, 1.11385}, {0.386, 1.05786}, {0.388, 1.10685}, {0.39, 
    1.16634}, {0.392, 0.700928}, {0.394, 1.16634}, {0.396, 1.21883}, {0.398, 
    1.12085}, {0.4, 1.05436}, {0.398, 1.31681}, {0.396, 1.12435}, {0.394, 
    1.00887}, {0.392, 1.14884}, {0.39, 1.56527}, {0.388, 0.693929}, {0.386, 
    0.483968}, {0.384, 0.186523}, {0.382, 0.410482}, {0.38, 0.211019}, {0.378,
     0.295003}, {0.376, 0.343994}, {0.374, 
    0.20752}, {0.372, -0.0164388}, {0.37, 0.357992}, {0.368, 
    0.357992}, {0.366, 
    0.0255534}, {0.364, -0.0199382}, {0.362, -0.00594076}, {0.36, 
    0.0605469}, {0.358, -0.212402}, {0.356, -0.0479329}, {0.354, -0.058431}, \
{0.352, -0.289388}, {0.35, -0.0199382}, {0.348, -0.292887}, {0.346, \
-0.191406}, {0.344, -0.310384}, {0.342, -0.166911}, {0.34, -0.348877}, \
{0.338, -0.282389}, {0.336, -0.0444336}, {0.334, -0.380371}, {0.332, \
-0.289388}, {0.33, -0.166911}, {0.328, -0.471354}, {0.326, -0.33488}, {0.324, \
-0.38737}, {0.322, -0.250895}, {0.32, -0.271891}, {0.318, -0.205404}, {0.316, \
-0.446859}, {0.314, -0.390869}, {0.312, -0.299886}, {0.31, -0.33488}, {0.308, \
-0.341878}, {0.306, -0.320882}, {0.304, -0.418864}, {0.302, -0.362874}, {0.3, \
-0.551839}, {0.298, -0.625326}, {0.296, -0.313883}, {0.294, -0.436361}, \
{0.292, -0.436361}, {0.29, -0.247396}, {0.288, -0.341878}, {0.286, \
-0.149414}, {0.284, -0.453857}, {0.282, -0.352376}, {0.28, -0.296387}, \
{0.278, -0.149414}, {0.276, -0.149414}, {0.274, -0.0409342}, {0.272, \
-0.27889}, {0.27, -0.429362}, {0.268, -0.0374349}, {0.266, -0.0829264}, \
{0.264, -0.289388}, {0.262, -0.607829}, {0.26, -0.359375}, {0.258, \
-0.240397}, {0.256, -0.194906}, {0.254, -0.156413}, {0.252, -0.33138}, {0.25, \
-0.488851}, {0.248, -0.320882}, {0.246, -0.292887}, {0.244, -0.394368}, \
{0.242, -0.446859}, {0.24, -0.0619303}, {0.238, -0.0654297}, {0.236, \
-0.114421}, {0.234, -0.509847}, {0.232, -0.103923}, {0.23, -0.152913}, \
{0.228, -0.128418}, {0.226, -0.450358}, {0.224, -0.296387}, {0.222, \
-0.268392}, {0.22, -0.369873}, {0.218, -0.0724284}, {0.216, -0.219401}, \
{0.214, -0.264893}, {0.212, -0.285889}, {0.21, -0.348877}, {0.208, \
-0.485352}, {0.206, -0.219401}, {0.204, -0.0864258}, {0.202, -0.282389}, \
{0.2, -0.366374}, {0.198, -0.443359}, {0.196, -0.180908}, {0.194, -0.159912}, \
{0.192, -0.310384}, {0.19, -0.460856}, {0.188, -0.247396}, {0.186, -0.27889}, \
{0.184, -0.27889}, {0.182, -0.516846}, {0.18, -0.366374}, {0.178, -0.285889}, \
{0.176, -0.296387}, {0.174, -0.166911}, {0.172, -0.264893}, {0.17, \
-0.285889}, {0.168, -0.33488}, {0.166, -0.229899}, {0.164, -0.303385}, \
{0.162, -0.268392}, {0.16, -0.156413}, {0.158, -0.390869}, {0.156, \
-0.341878}, {0.154, -0.159912}, {0.152, -0.397868}, {0.15, -0.236898}, \
{0.148, -0.394368}, {0.146, -0.33138}, {0.144, -0.348877}, {0.142, \
-0.369873}, {0.14, -0.17041}, {0.138, -0.394368}, {0.136, -0.338379}, {0.134, \
-0.268392}, {0.132, -0.306885}, {0.13, -0.2229}, {0.128, -0.275391}, {0.126, \
-0.299886}, {0.124, -0.247396}, {0.122, -0.327881}, {0.12, -0.418864}, \
{0.118, -0.394368}, {0.116, -0.156413}, {0.114, -0.380371}, {0.112, \
-0.352376}, {0.11, -0.135417}, {0.108, -0.397868}, {0.106, -0.404867}, \
{0.104, -0.397868}, {0.102, -0.33138}, {0.1, -0.17391}, {0.098, -0.345378}, \
{0.096, -0.348877}, {0.094, -0.348877}, {0.092, -0.355876}, {0.09, \
-0.366374}, {0.088, -0.436361}, {0.086, -0.359375}, {0.084, -0.292887}, \
{0.082, -0.380371}, {0.08, -0.534342}, {0.078, -0.285889}, {0.076, -0.33138}, \
{0.074, -0.327881}, {0.072, -0.180908}, {0.07, -0.268392}, {0.068, \
-0.310384}, {0.066, -0.352376}, {0.064, -0.436361}, {0.062, -0.229899}, \
{0.06, -0.292887}, {0.058, -0.338379}, {0.056, -0.373372}, {0.054, \
-0.513346}, {0.052, -0.338379}, {0.05, -0.240397}, {0.048, -0.275391}, \
{0.046, -0.513346}, {0.044, -0.446859}, {0.042, -0.338379}, {0.04, \
-0.268392}, {0.038, -0.320882}, {0.036, -0.219401}, {0.034, -0.432861}, \
{0.032, -0.317383}, {0.03, -0.376872}, {0.028, -0.471354}, {0.026, \
-0.345378}, {0.024, -0.366374}, {0.022, -0.401367}, {0.02, -0.527344}, \
{0.018, -0.485352}, {0.016, -0.271891}, {0.014, -0.27889}, {0.012, \
-0.453857}, {0.01, -0.527344}, {0.008, -0.366374}, {0.006, -0.366374}, \
{0.004, -0.194906}, {0.002, -0.369873}, {1.25*10^-16, -0.485352}, {-0.002, \
-0.597331}, {-0.004, -0.338379}, {-0.006, -0.380371}, {-0.008, -0.394368}, \
{-0.01, -0.443359}, {-0.012, -0.285889}, {-0.014, -0.436361}, {-0.016, \
-0.516846}, {-0.018, -0.418864}, {-0.02, -0.338379}, {-0.022, -0.320882}, \
{-0.024, -0.317383}, {-0.026, -0.33488}, {-0.028, -0.327881}, {-0.03, \
-0.2264}, {-0.032, -0.317383}, {-0.034, -0.359375}, {-0.036, -0.38387}, \
{-0.038, -0.576335}, {-0.04, -0.677816}, {-0.042, -0.418864}, {-0.044, \
-0.558838}, {-0.046, -0.450358}, {-0.048, -0.499349}, {-0.05, -0.352376}, \
{-0.052, -0.527344}, {-0.054, -0.159912}, {-0.056, -0.523844}, {-0.058, \
-0.257894}, {-0.06, -0.460856}, {-0.062, -0.369873}, {-0.064, -0.397868}, \
{-0.066, -0.614827}, {-0.068, -0.516846}, {-0.07, -0.257894}, {-0.072, \
-0.558838}, {-0.074, -0.415365}, {-0.076, -0.730306}, {-0.078, -0.296387}, \
{-0.08, -0.523844}, {-0.082, -0.49585}, {-0.084, -0.502848}, {-0.086, \
-0.562337}, {-0.088, -0.562337}, {-0.09, -0.310384}, {-0.092, -0.373372}, \
{-0.094, -0.373372}, {-0.096, -0.320882}, {-0.098, -0.380371}, {-0.1, \
-0.530843}, {-0.102, -0.397868}, {-0.104, -0.572835}, {-0.106, -0.516846}, \
{-0.108, -0.408366}, {-0.11, -0.380371}, {-0.112, -0.527344}, {-0.114, \
-0.478353}, {-0.116, -0.579834}, {-0.118, -0.425863}, {-0.12, -0.310384}, \
{-0.122, -0.457357}, {-0.124, -0.520345}, {-0.126, -0.338379}, {-0.128, \
-0.27889}, {-0.13, -0.579834}, {-0.132, -0.555339}, {-0.134, -0.593831}, \
{-0.136, -0.541341}, {-0.138, -0.464355}, {-0.14, -0.534342}, {-0.142, \
-0.450358}, {-0.144, -0.432861}, {-0.146, -0.366374}, {-0.148, -0.478353}, \
{-0.15, -0.443359}, {-0.152, -0.488851}, {-0.154, -0.681315}, {-0.156, \
-0.635824}, {-0.158, -0.345378}, {-0.16, -0.49585}, {-0.162, -0.597331}, \
{-0.164, -0.502848}, {-0.166, -0.485352}, {-0.168, -0.621826}, {-0.17, \
-0.516846}, {-0.172, -0.625326}, {-0.174, -0.572835}, {-0.176, -0.478353}, \
{-0.178, -0.569336}, {-0.18, -0.569336}, {-0.182, -0.569336}, {-0.184, \
-0.712809}, {-0.186, -0.723307}, {-0.188, -0.569336}, {-0.19, -0.586833}, \
{-0.192, -0.604329}, {-0.194, -0.674316}, {-0.196, -0.688314}, {-0.198, \
-0.614827}, {-0.2, -0.747803}};
```

Splitting the data

```
data2 = {First[#], Flatten[Rest[#], 1]} &@Split[data, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &];

f1[x_] = FindFormula[data2[[1]], x,
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
  SpecificityGoal -> "High",
  RandomSeeding -> 0]

(* 0.298829 + 0.356977 x - 3.21678 x^2 + 18.5331 x^3 *)

x1min = Min[data2[[1, All, 1]]]

(* -0.198 *)

f2[x_] = FindFormula[data2[[2]], x,
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
  SpecificityGoal -> "High",
  RandomSeeding -> 0]

(* -0.377387 + 0.767637 x - 6.16336 x^2 - 13.9907 x^3 + 429.278 x^4 - 
 111.08 x^5 - 8809.58 x^6 + 18052.7 x^7 *)

x2min = Min[data2[[2, All, 1]]]

(* -0.2 *)
```

While the starting point for each curve (`x1min` and `x2min`) is taken from the respective data segments, the stopping point for both curves is where the curves intersect, i.e., where `f1[x] == f2[x]`

```
xmax = x /. NSolve[f1[x] == f2[x], x, Reals][[1]]

(* 0.394405 *)

Show[
 ListLinePlot[Flatten[data2, 1],
  PlotStyle -> LightBlue],
 Plot[f1[x], {x, x1min, xmax}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All],
 Plot[f2[x], {x, x2min, xmax}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All],
 PlotRange -> {{-0.3, 0.5}, {-1, 2}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bob this method is the best for my case. I will try it for the other curves I have and let you know the results. :)

Comment: I would appreciate if you can tell me this line is for what in your code:
xmax = x /. NSolve[f1[x] == f2[x], x, Reals][[1]]

Comment: @HendMkaouar - It identifies the max value of x to use in drawing each curve, i.e., stop when the two curves intersect.

Answer (score 8):

*(Comment in order to clarify the question.)*

Is this what you want to get?

[image]

If yes, that can be done with Quantile Regression as explained in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125001/34008) for the question you linked in your answer, ["Remove noise from data"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124928/34008).

Or using `MovingAverage[data,20]` as @kirma commented.

[image]

Comment: yes this is good enough but how did you choose the parameters: 0.25 and 0.75?

Comment: @HendMkaouar Well, I just assumed and then verified that your data has equal parts above and below the quantile 0.5. Since you expressed interest in this solution I post better explanations in my answer.

Comment: @HendMkaouar Also, please consider editing your question with clarifications. (It would get more upvotes...)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will try to clarify more my question with a picture that explains my data and the data it should be.

Answer (score 5):

Another way might be to use [`EstimatedBackground`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EstimatedBackground.html?q=EstimatedBackground) to estimate the data's envelope and then average it.

First split the data into two:

```
{data1, data2} = {#1, Join[##2]} & @@ Split[data, Sign[#1[[1]] - #2[[1]]] == -1 &];
```

The backgrounds of the first half of the data and its average:

```
lo1 = Transpose[{#1, EstimatedBackground[#2, 10]}] & @@ Transpose[data1];
hi1 = Transpose[{#1, -EstimatedBackground[-#2, 10]}] & @@ Transpose[data1];
smooth1 = Mean[{lo1, hi1}];

ListLinePlot[{data1, lo1, hi1, smooth1}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.5], Red, Red, Black}]
```

[image]

Both pieces of data:

```
lo2 = Transpose[{#1, EstimatedBackground[#2]}] & @@ Transpose[data2];
hi2 = Transpose[{#1, -EstimatedBackground[-#2]}] & @@ Transpose[data2];
smooth2 = Mean[{lo2, hi2}];

Show[
  ListLinePlot[{data1, smooth1}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.5], Red}],
  ListLinePlot[{data2, smooth2}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.5], Red}, PlotRange -> All],
  PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Chip for the reply, this one is also good :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised no one used actual signal filtering yet.

```
fq = 0.015;
ts = Table[{i, data[[i, 2]]}, {i, 1, Length[data]}];
fx = LowpassFilter[TimeSeries@ts, Quantity[fq, "Hertz"]];
ts2 = Table[{i, data[[i, 1]]}, {i, 1, Length[data]}];
fx2 = LowpassFilter[TimeSeries@ts2, Quantity[fq, "Hertz"]];
ListPlot[Table[{fx2[i], fx[i]}, {i, 1, Length[data]}]]
```

fq=0.015:

[image]

fq=0.005:

[image]