# Parting a table by second column elements

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting, table

I have 2 X m table with elements {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, .... {xi, yi}, .....{xm, ym}}. It is an experimental data, which can be seen in the attached picture. There is a significant noise and arbitrariness in the variation of independent parameter (first column, x) as well as dependent double valued parameter (second column, y). Here, I want to divide the data into two parts- one which has almost constant y and another with y increasing with x. How to achieve it as the inflection point may not be in the center of the table.

Will appreciate any suggestion. Thanks[image]
Here is a sample data -

```
{{40.3595,0.001477},{40.9698,-0.007586},{38.0707,-0.013534},{39.5966,-0.003783},{42.6483,0.004349},{43.869,-0.00443},{39.7491,-0.006777},{42.4957,-0.00002},{43.7164,0.001113},{41.3513,-0.002448},{43.9453,0.000263},{46.463,0.004875},{44.7845,-0.000506},{43.4113,-0.000182},{43.7164,0.00617},{47.3022,0.004268},{45.2423,0.000829},{43.4875,0.005887},{46.3867,0.012643},{46.6156,0.003864},{46.7682,-0.001153},{48.2941,0.008921},{45.2423,0.013008},{48.2178,0.00532},{48.6755,0.004956},{48.0652,0.015718},{49.1333,0.011996},{50.4303,0.008152},{48.5992,0.013534},{50.8881,0.019198},{52.0325,0.014343},{50.4303,0.013088},{49.3622,0.016487},{52.7954,0.012117},{52.1851,0.010863},{50.7355,0.019683},{51.1169,0.025428},{53.4821,0.016649},{52.2614,0.011268},{47.9126,0.022273},{52.8717,0.025186},{53.1769,0.021828},{52.2614,0.017782},{55.6946,0.02644},{55.6946,0.024457},{51.1169,0.021221},{53.0243,0.025469},{58.2886,0.026804},{56.6864,0.023486},{56.6101,0.026683},{55.4657,0.035098},{56.839,0.030324},{56.6101,0.02381},{56.4575,0.028908},{58.3649,0.033561},{59.8145,0.026238},{56.4575,0.026521},{57.373,0.036797},{59.6619,0.035584},{59.967,0.02648},{58.5938,0.030203},{58.5175,0.037971},{60.3485,0.034896},{61.4929,0.030364},{60.0433,0.035705},{61.3403,0.035988},{61.1877,0.031052},{60.73,0.032671},{61.9507,0.0423},{62.8662,0.038254},{62.9425,0.029474},{60.9589,0.039508},{61.9507,0.046305},{65.155,0.034977},{62.7136,0.033803},{62.9425,0.045294},{65.155,0.043837},{63.4003,0.039063},{63.2477,0.043797},{68.4357,0.048166},{66.6046,0.048247},{64.621,0.042583},{65.155,0.049663},{67.5964,0.049299},{66.0706,0.046629},{66.2231,0.049097},{67.3676,0.05379},{68.2068,0.045456},{66.7572,0.042259},{65.5365,0.056541},{68.8171,0.054963},{71.5637,0.044646},{67.5201,0.043716},{67.5964,0.055773},{66.6809,0.056056},{67.5201,0.049299},{67.4438,0.049501},{66.7572,0.054437},{65.918,0.052981},{67.4438,0.053669},{66.2231,0.056218},{67.3676,0.050634},{65.4602,0.048288},{64.4684,0.055732},{66.0706,0.056541},{67.2913,0.049259},{65.3839,0.046629},{64.6973,0.059171},{64.0869,0.061315},{65.4602,0.052415},{62.8662,0.049501},{63.9343,0.058483},{63.5529,0.056703},{63.1714,0.050634},{61.4166,0.052779},{64.1632,0.055611},{63.2477,0.055449},{60.1196,0.054073},{58.8989,0.056825},{62.561,0.05205},{61.7218,0.0476},{59.8145,0.056784},{58.67,0.058079},{61.1115,0.052172},{58.2123,0.049097},{58.136,0.060304},{59.8907,0.063338},{58.5175,0.052576},{56.1523,0.0476},{56.6864,0.053062},{58.3649,0.052698},{55.6946,0.050351},{48.2941,0.053264},{55.2368,0.052415},{56.839,0.051848},{55.9998,0.052293},{55.0079,0.057148},{53.1769,0.049056},{54.1687,0.043999},{55.3894,0.053264},{54.8553,0.058888},{53.3295,0.048935},{50.2777,0.043999},{53.1006,0.056096},{53.2532,0.061032},{51.8799,0.046912},{49.8199,0.046184},{50.4303,0.050837},{52.5665,0.049259},{51.1169,0.046346},{49.1333,0.051929},{50.6592,0.045172},{49.1333,0.043069},{49.5911,0.051363},{50.0488,0.053264},{50.2777,0.04323},{47.6074,0.035341},{46.463,0.049866},{48.6755,0.058322},{48.6755,0.042098},{44.9371,0.037},{45.166,0.048773},{47.76,0.054802},{47.76,0.0476},{45.2423,0.048571},{44.3268,0.047155},{45.4712,0.048207},{44.8608,0.047843},{44.0216,0.054559},{43.1824,0.048652},{43.2587,0.042219},{43.6401,0.050756},{41.6565,0.054235},{41.7328,0.042502},{39.978,0.035867},{39.1388,0.051524},{42.4957,0.058928},{42.7246,0.046508},{39.444,0.040479},{41.6565,0.050027},{40.741,0.053628}}
```

Comment: Without concrete data, it will be difficult to give concrete answers. That being said, take a look at [`TakeDrop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TakeDrop.html) (to split the list), and [`Ordering`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html) (to find the position of the rightmost point)

Comment: You can use `FindFormula` or [`QuantileRegression`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/QuantileRegression/). Here is a very similar MSE question: ["Smoothing noisy data"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/177029/smoothing-noisy-data).

Comment: Thanks for the response - I have included a section of data on either side of inflection point. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Store your data in d. Then we plot  the x and y values separately:

```
ListLinePlot[d[[All, 2]], PlotLabel -> "y values"]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[d[[All, 1]], PlotLabel -> "x values"]
```

[image]

You can see that the x and y values increase up to index 89. From there the x values decrease again, but the y values stay approx. constant.

The division of the data into two sets: d1 and d2 is therefore simple, take the first 89 points and the rest:

```
d1= Take[d,;;89];
d2= Take[d,90;;];
```

Comment: This works when the data is sorted (as it is the case in OP's question.) Some generality is achieved if the data is sorted with, say, `SortBy[d, #[[1]] / #[[2]]& ]`

Answer (score 2):

I am going to use [QRMon](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2018/08/01/a-monad-for-quantile-regression-workflows/) because the workflow is easier to specify.

##### Procedure

1. Fit Quantile Regression (QR) curves:

   1. Using small number of knots
   2. At different probabilities (e.g. 0.25 and 0.75)
   3. With different, *low* interpolation orders (e.g. 0, 1, 2)
2. Select QR parameters to extract the "near constant y" points.
3. Pick the points around produced regression quantile.

   1. Using suitable pick range (e.g. 0.015)
4. Plot the original data points and the extracted ones.

##### Code

```mathematica
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/MonadicProgramming/MonadicQuantileRegression.m"]
```

```mathematica
qrObj = 
   QRMonUnit[data]⟹
    QRMonEchoDataSummary⟹
    QRMonQuantileRegression[4, {0.25, 0.75, 0.85}, InterpolationOrder -> 0]⟹
    QRMonPlot[];
```

[image]

[image]

```mathematica
qrObj = 
   QRMonUnit[data]⟹
    QRMonQuantileRegression[1, {0.25, 0.75, 0.85}, InterpolationOrder -> 0]⟹
    QRMonPlot[]⟹
    QRMonPickPathPoints[0.015];
```

[image]

```mathematica
lsConstantYPoints = (qrObj⟹QRMonTakeValue)[0.75]

(*{{58.5175, 0.037971}, {61.9507, 0.0423}, {62.8662, 0.038254}, {60.9589, 0.039508}, {61.9507, 0.046305}, {62.9425, 0.045294}, {65.155, 0.043837}, {63.4003, 0.039063}, {63.2477, 0.043797}, {68.4357, 0.048166}, {66.6046, 0.048247}, {64.621, 0.042583}, {65.155, 0.049663}, {67.5964, 0.049299}, {66.0706, 0.046629}, {66.2231, 0.049097}, {67.3676, 0.05379}, {68.2068, 0.045456}, {66.7572, 0.042259}, {65.5365, 0.056541}, {68.8171, 0.054963}, {71.5637, 0.044646}, {67.5201, 0.043716}, {67.5964, 0.055773}, {66.6809, 0.056056}, {67.5201, 0.049299}, {67.4438, 0.049501}, {66.7572, 0.054437}, {65.918, 0.052981}, {67.4438, 0.053669}, {66.2231, 0.056218}, {67.3676, 0.050634}, {65.4602, 0.048288}, {64.4684, 0.055732}, {66.0706, 0.056541}, {67.2913, 0.049259}, {65.3839, 0.046629}, {64.6973, 0.059171}, {64.0869, 0.061315}, {65.4602, 0.052415}, {62.8662, 0.049501}, {63.9343, 0.058483}, {63.5529, 0.056703}, {63.1714, 0.050634}, {61.4166, 0.052779}, {64.1632, 0.055611}, {63.2477, 0.055449}, {60.1196, 0.054073}, {58.8989, 0.056825}, {62.561, 0.05205}, {61.7218, 0.0476}, {59.8145, 0.056784}, {58.67, 0.058079}, {61.1115, 0.052172}, {58.2123, 0.049097}, {58.136, 0.060304}, {59.8907, 0.063338}, {58.5175, 0.052576}, {56.1523, 0.0476}, {56.6864, 0.053062}, {58.3649, 0.052698}, {55.6946, 0.050351}, {48.2941, 0.053264}, {55.2368, 0.052415}, {56.839, 0.051848}, {55.9998, 0.052293}, {55.0079, 0.057148}, {53.1769, 0.049056}, {54.1687, 0.043999}, {55.3894, 0.053264}, {54.8553, 0.058888}, {53.3295, 0.048935}, {50.2777, 0.043999}, {53.1006, 0.056096}, {53.2532, 0.061032}, {51.8799, 0.046912}, {49.8199, 0.046184}, {50.4303, 0.050837}, {52.5665, 0.049259}, {51.1169, 0.046346}, {49.1333, 0.051929}, {50.6592, 0.045172}, {49.1333, 0.043069}, {49.5911, 0.051363}, {50.0488, 0.053264}, {50.2777, 0.04323}, {46.463, 0.049866}, {48.6755, 0.058322}, {48.6755, 0.042098}, {44.9371, 0.037}, {45.166, 0.048773}, {47.76, 0.054802}, {47.76, 0.0476}, {45.2423, 0.048571}, {44.3268, 0.047155}, {45.4712, 0.048207}, {44.8608, 0.047843}, {44.0216, 0.054559}, {43.1824, 0.048652}, {43.2587, 0.042219}, {43.6401, 0.050756}, {41.6565, 0.054235}, {41.7328, 0.042502}, {39.1388, 0.051524}, {42.4957, 0.058928}, {42.7246, 0.046508}, {39.444, 0.040479}, {41.6565, 0.050027}, {40.741, 0.053628}}*)
```

```mathematica
ListPlot[{data, lsConstantYPoints}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotStyle -> {{GrayLevel[0.8], PointSize[0.02]}, {Red, PointSize[0.006]}}, PlotLegends -> {"data", "extracted"}]
```

[image]