# Efficient way to detect peak value changes in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, peak-detection

```
ListPlot[list, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

I would like a simple method to get the positions within the list where the values deviate a lot from their previous values. If I just use a threshold, I might miss some peaks or introduce wrong results as the values before a peak can vary.

Here is the list:

```
list = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/ncJDt0L4", "List"]
```

I was thinking of using a numeric gradient, but I don't know if *Mathematica* has a build in function and also if this is really the best method.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention: A peak should always be chosen with respect to the previous points which lie after the last detected peak, or in other terms: All values before the last detected peak should not be considered in evaluating the next peak. Only the values after the last detected peak are of importance.

The first small peaks before the first big peak should not be detexted as peaks since the data fluctuates a lot there

...and the last little peak should not be counted as peaks, because there cannot be two peaks when the distance (x) between the peak position is less than 3.

Comment: Look up `ListConvolve`.

Comment: @rhermans Thanks for the edit ! :)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Interesting, thanks for the note. How would you use it in this case?

Comment: `ListConvlve` the data with a "center-surround" filter that will "pick out" peaks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FindPeaks` is [the perfect solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/180018/2036) as it has all the options to fine tune the condition you require for a peak:

```
list = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/ncJDt0L4", "List"];

peaks = FindPeaks[list, 3, 12];
ListLogPlot[{list, peaks}, PlotRange -> Full, Joined -> {True, False},
  PlotStyle -> {Thin, Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]}]
```

[image]

Just play around with the values for [Gaussain blurring, minimum sharpness and threshold](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindPeaks.html) until you get the performance you want.

**Edit**

The log-plot is very useful for highlighting the reason, why the smallest peaks are also considered a peak. In case you do not consider it a peak, you can easily eliminate the very small but sharp features by also using the threshold, the fourth argument of `FindPeaks`.

For a direct comparison with other solutions, here is a linear plot:

```
ListPlot[{list, peaks}, PlotRange -> Full, Joined -> {True, False}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thin, Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks  a lot ! The Log plot is great, but can you also add a linear plot for direct comparaison with the other answers?

Comment: @james Here you go.

Comment: Great !! Thank you ! :))

Answer (score 5):

Using `FindPeaks` is [a fine solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/180018/34008). This answer responds to the following OP statements/questions.

> I would like a simple method to get the positions within the list where the values deviate a lot from their previous values. If I just use a threshold, I might miss some peaks or introduce wrong results as the values before a peak can vary.
>
> I was thinking of using a numeric gradient, but I don't know if Mathematica has a build in function

Get the (consecutive) differences:

```
ds = Differences[list];
Through[{Min, Max, Mean, Median, StandardDeviation}[ds]]

(* {-24958.8, 25131.1, 0.526443, -1.1353, 2896.09} *)
```

Pick peak positions with a threshold (0.06 here):

```
ds2 = Select[ds, # > 0 &];
pos = Pick[Range[2, Length[list]], 
  Map[ # > Mean[ds2] + 0.06*StandardDeviation[ds2] &, ds]]
```

Plot data and peaks:

```
list2 = Transpose[{Range[Length[list]], list}];
ListLinePlot[list2, PlotRange -> Full, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[list2[[pos]]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Do you see a method of how to avoid those initial peaks, because they should theoretically not be seen as peaks.

Comment: see Edited question

Comment: @james I thought the initial peaks are important! ;) And yes there is a method to avoid them...

Comment: okay, awesome. Looking forward seeing it.

Comment: which method is it that you were thinking of ?

Comment: @james [Quantile Regression](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2018/08/01/a-monad-for-quantile-regression-workflows/). See this MSE post : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125001/34008 .

Comment: Thank you for the link. I am having difficulties understanding the method. If you have the time and if it is not too much asked, do you think that you could add the solution to your answer ?

Comment: @james I will post another answer later today.

Comment: Thanks so much !

Comment: @james I did experiment with Quantile regression on this but the results are not much better...

Comment: Okay, well thanks a lot for trying!

Answer (score 4):

I think that you are likely looking for some combination of the parameters of the `FindPeak` function, for example:

```
list = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/ncJDt0L4", "List"];

peaks = FindPeaks[list, Automatic, Automatic, 500];
ListLinePlot[
 list,
 PlotRange -> Full,
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[peaks]}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Do you see a method of how to avoid those initial peaks, because they should theoretically not be seen as peaks.

Comment: @james Why shouldn't they be seen as peaks?

Comment: The values before the first peak fluctuate and hence should not be seen as peaks, but rather as noise with respect to the first peak. I forgot to mention: The peaks should always be chosen with respect to the previous points which lie after the last peak.

Comment: @james Is there a specific minimum separation between peaks before they are seen as separate peaks, rather than part of some larger peak?

Comment: Hmm, good question. Yes, in principle, the minimum separation would probably be 3.

Comment: `FindPeaks` is exactly for this purpose. It has extra options to set required derivetives and contrasts to be considered a peak. Have you not noticed these options or are they not suitable for you?