# How to generate a RandomVariate of a custom distribution?

Tags: random, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I'm trying to generate a pseudorandom variate out of a custom distribution. Suppose I want define a custom distribution, and for the sake of simplicity I define a Poisson distribution (the distribution I want is a derived mixture of two Poisson distributions):

```
custom[a_] := ProbabilityDistribution[(a^k Exp[-a])/k!, {k, 0, ∞, 1}];
```

When I now try to generate a `RandomVariate[]` of that distribution,

```
RandomVariate[custom[2], 10]
```

I obtain the following error:

> `RandomVariate::noimp: Sampling from ProbabilityDistribution[2^x/(E^2 x!),{x,0,∞,1}] is not implemented.`

For the record, when the distribution is defined as a continuous distribution:

```
custom[a_] := ProbabilityDistribution[(a^k Exp[-a])/k!, {k, 0, ∞}];
```

there is no problem with the use of `RandomVariate`.

I'd appreciate some insight into this problem, thanks!

Comment: It would work if for instance your new distribution is derived from a known one via `TransformedDistribution` as in `RandomVariate[
 TransformedDistribution[x - 1, 
   x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]] // Release, 15]`

Comment: "the distribution I want is a derived mixture of two Poisson distributions" - could you maybe specify how the two Poisson distributions are mixed? I presume you've tried `MixtureDistribution[]` already?

Comment: FWIW: it looks to me (after some experimentation) that `RandomVariate[]` is not equipped to handle arbitrary discrete probability distributions; in general, you might have to roll your own algorithm.

Comment: @J.M. why does `RandomVariate[\[ScriptCapitalD], 15]` from http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html works though?

Comment: @J.M. and more importantly why is it wrong?? `Show[Plot[PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD], x], {x, -5, 5}], 
 RandomVariate[\[ScriptCapitalD], 1500]//Histogram[#, Automatic, "Probability"]&]`

Comment: @chris Kudos for `Release`!

Comment: @chris I did not know of existence of `Release`. The current way is to use `Evaluate`. The kudos was because I learned something new.

Comment: @Sasha ah! that's just because I learned mathematica 1.2 which had `Release` which has been depreciated since

Comment: @Sasha I think you just learned something old

Comment: @Sasha, think of `Release[]` as what *Mathematica* had before they split up that function into `ReleaseHold[]` and `Evaluate[]`. A chimera, if you will...

Comment: @chris, sounds like a new question...

Comment: @J.M. I have: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14009/inconsistency-in-histograms-probability-binsize

Comment: @Rojo old is beautiful ;-)

Answer (score 19):

The short answer is: I don't think it is built to always work for general distributions (though see Sjoerd C. de Vries's answer and  continuous example below).
You might also want to have a look at the nice tutorial how to [Create Your Own Distribution
with Oleksandr Pavlyk](http://www.wolfram.co.uk/events/technology-conference/2011/mathematics-and-statistics.html).

Lets see what are your options

**Mixture**

For mixture distributions, following J. M., we can define a mixture as:

```
DD[μ_, ν_, a_, b_] =
               MixtureDistribution[{a, b}, {PoissonDistribution[μ], PoissonDistribution[ν]}]
```

so that

```
RandomVariate[DD[4, 3, 1, 2], 16]

(* {5, 5, 6, 3, 5, 7, 9, 1, 3, 7, 5, 5, 3, 5, 2, 3} *)
```

**Transformation**

One can also use `TransformedDistribution` to define a new distribution from a
known one, and draw from it:

```
RandomVariate[TransformedDistribution[x - 4,
  x \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[10]] // Release, 15]
```

**Draw via Cumulative Distrubution**

For a set of distributions for which the cumulative distribution exists, within which your example falls (though it probably differs from what you really want to do), the inverse of the cumulative distribution can be used to define a draw:

```
 CDF[custom[a], x]

 (* Gamma[1 + Floor[x], a]/Gamma[1 + Floor[x]] *)
```

So for instance,

```
  g[x_] = CDF[custom[10], x];
  h = Table[{g[x], x}, {x, 0, 40}] // N // Interpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> 0] &;
```

which allows us to  define the inverse of the CDF:

```
  h /@ (RandomReal[{0, 1}, {12}])

  (*  {12., 15., 6., 17., 12., 8., 6., 9., 8., 13., 13., 12.} *)

  Show[h /@ (RandomReal[{0, 1}, {125000}]) // Histogram[#, Automatic, "Probability"] &, 
       Plot[PDF[custom[10], x - 1/2], {x, 0, 20}]]
```

[image: histogram and PDF of custom distribution]

**Empirical Distribution**

For a more general class of distribution, there is a twisted route within the current set of existing *Mathematica* functions: if you can draw samples which satisfy the distribution, then you can derive an `EmpiricalDistribution` (thanks J. M.) from your sample and then draw through it. It might be useful if it's costly to draw in the first place.

**Continuous distribution where `ProbabilityDistribution` works with `Random Variate`**

```
norm = Integrate[Exp[-x^2]/(c^2 + x^2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity},Assumptions -> c > 0]; 
DD[c_] = ProbabilityDistribution[1/norm Exp[-x^2]/(c^2 + x^2),
  {x, -Infinity,Infinity},Assumptions -> c > 0];
```

Let's check that the random variate sample is consistent

```
 data =RandomVariate[DD[4], 1500];

 DDE = EmpiricalDistribution[data];
 {Plot[CDF[DD[4], x] // Release, {x, -4, 4},PlotStyle -> Directive[Red]], 
  Plot[CDF[DDE, x], {x, -4, 4}]} // Show
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that it can involve more than one parameter:

```
 norm = Integrate[Exp[-β x^2]/(c^2 + x^2),{x,-Infinity,Infinity},Assumptions->{c > 0, β>0}];
 DD[c_, β_] = ProbabilityDistribution[1/norm Exp[-β x^2]/(c^2 + x^2),
  {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> (c > 0 && β > 0)];

 RandomVariate[DD[1, 1], 4]

 (* {0.149204,-0.644442,-0.632239,-0.266628} *)
```

*Final Note*

For 2D generalization see [RandomVariate from 2-dimensional probability distribution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2635/randomvariate-from-2-dimensional-probability-distribution/2649#2649)

Comment: Since OP is sampling from a discrete distribution, `EmpiricalDistribution[]` might be more appropriate...

Answer (score 12):

I have a hunch that the problem lies in the use of `Infinity` in combination with a finite step. So, it's not an issue of continuous vs discrete. Replace $\infty$ with a sufficiently large number (with the factorial involved 100 should be OK) and it works:

```
custom[a_] := ProbabilityDistribution[(a^k Exp[-a])/k!, {k, 0, 100, 1}];

RandomVariate[custom[2], 10]
```

> {2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1}

Let's test whether a set of 10 million random draws from the custom distribution are described by a Poisson distribution with the same parameter:

```
EstimatedDistribution[RandomVariate[custom[2], 10000000], PoissonDistribution[λ]]
```

> PoissonDistribution[1.9999276]

```
EstimatedDistribution[RandomVariate[custom[8.5], 10000000], PoissonDistribution[λ]]
```

> PoissonDistribution[8.5006323]

Comment: so it would be a kind of bug that it does not work?

Comment: @chris One man's bug is another man's feauture ;-) Anyway, there are various Mathematica functions like `Sum` that handle infinite series and can deal with them in a symbolic way. It just seems that `ProbabilityDistribution` isn't one of them.

Comment: I see your point; nonetheless its a bit unfortunate because quite a few distributions have infinities in their domain.

Comment: `ProbabilityDistribution` is not able to sample custom univariate discrete distribution because it does not know where the majority of the probability is concentrated. Sjoerd's workaround is enabling, provided truncated density is properly re-normalized, because he manually truncated the density to where most density is concentrated.

Comment: This is actually very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is trivially easy with [mathStatica for *Mathematica*](http://www.mathstatica.com/), for ANY arbitrary discrete distribution. For the original poster's problem:

```
f = Exp[-a] a^x / x!;
domain[f] = {x, 0, Infinity} &&  {a > 0}  &&  {Discrete};
```

Here are 10 pseudo-random drawings:

```
RandomNumber[10, f /. a -> 2]
{2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 7}
```

And here are 100,000 more:

```
data = RandomNumber[100000, f /. a -> 2];
```

Next, compare a frequency plot of the empirical sample data we have just generated (the red dots) to the parent symbolic pmf (in blue):

```
FrequencyPlotDiscrete[data, f /. a -> 2]
```

[image: freqplot]

Splendido. Just as easy for anything else :)

We have a chapter on these sorts of issues... see Chapter 3 of: Rose and Smith (Nov. 2011), Mathematical Statistics with *Mathematica*.