# Inconsistency in Histogram's "Probability" Binsize

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

**Context**

Let me define a Probability distribution (following the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html) and with some connection to this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13981/how-to-generate-a-randomvariate-of-a-custom-distribution/13984#13984))

```
 DD = ProbabilityDistribution[(Sqrt[2]/\[Pi]) (1/(1 + x^4)), {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}];
```

which is normalized properly `CDF[DD,1000]//N` (* 1 *), and looks like this

```
 Plot[Evaluate[PDF[DD, x]], {x, -4, 4}, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am interested in drawing samples from this distribution

If I let *Mathematica* do his job:

```
 Show[RandomVariate[DD, 1500] // Histogram[#, Automatic, "Probability"] &,
  Plot[PDF[DD, x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]]
```

I get this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which strongly suggests it got the normalisation wrong.

**Question**

> Is this a known bug or a misunderstanding on how `Histogram` works on my part?

**Attempt**

Now let me evaluate by hand its normalized histogram

```
 hh = RandomVariate[DD, 15000]//BinCounts[#, {-5, 5, 1/4}] &;
 h = 4 hh/Total[hh];
 h = Transpose[{Table[i - 1/4, {i, -5 + 1/4, 5, 1/4}], h}];
```

I get this

```
 Show[ListLinePlot[h, InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Axis], 
 Plot[PDF[DD, x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Turning back to the *Mathematica* Automated procedure, if I force the binsize *and* the corresponding Normalization, I get this

```
Show[RandomVariate[DD, 150000]//Histogram[#, {-5, 5, 1/4}, "Probability"] &,
Plot[PDF[DD, x]/4, {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But note the `1/4` factor in the `PDF` (corresponding to the binsize).

Comment: If you use `"PDF"` instead of `"Probability"`, then the scaling comes out right...

Comment: @J.M. so it was a trap! You knew the answer: how wicked! Well you can write it as a one-liner now :-)

Comment: Well, you got a dandy answer from jVincent, so it still turned out pretty darn good, eh? :)

Comment: @J.M. are you guys working as a team?

Comment: Nope; I'm pretty sure we've never met before...

Comment: :-) All scams partners are in denial when caught red-handed!

Comment: FWIW: `HistogramDistribution[]` would have been a slightly tidier way to do your attempt.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. I was wondering about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because of the different meanings of the graphs. For the bar chart, the probability of being within the width for any given bar is equal to the height. So, the density in a bar is given by height/width. So, when comparing to the probability density function (PDF), they shouldn't have the same height; they should be such that the bar chart is at the same height divided by the width of the bars. Notice that your boxes are `1/4` wide and this is where your inconsistency comes from.

Note that histogram can also scale to show the PDF instead; simply use

```
Show[RandomVariate[DD, 1500] // Histogram[#, Automatic, "PDF"] &, 
Plot[PDF[DD, x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks; having suffered a bit on this I ll probably remember it ;-)