# How to simulate with a user specified bivariate continuous probability distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I am very new to *Mathematica* set up and I have the following question: I have a bivariate probability distribution which is a little complicated and of the form:

$$f(x,y)=(a_0+a_1+a_2)\frac{a_1 a_2}{a_0}\exp(-a_1 x-a_2 y)\left\{1-\exp\left[-a_0\min(x,y)\right]\right\}$$

such that, $x>0$ and $y>0$.

I need to simulate from the above distribution.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Look up `RandomVariate[]` and `ProbabilityDistribution[]`.

Comment: Also closely related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13981/how-to-generate-a-randomvariate-of-a-custom-distribution

Answer (score 2):

If I understood it correctly, you can try this:

```
pdf[x_, y_] := (a0 + a1 + a2)*((a1*a2)/a0)*Exp[-a1 x - a2 y]*(1 - Exp[-a0 Min[x, y]])
```

and then, assigning the value of 1 to `a0`, `a1` and `a2`, you can plot it:

```
Plot3D[Evaluate@pdf[x, y] /. {a0 -> 1, a1 -> 1, a2 -> 1}, 
  {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 6}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> Full, Exclusions -> None]
```

Result:

[image]

**EDITED**

If you want to "simulate" from the continuous probability distribution, you might want to use `Manipulate[]` to see what happens when you change parameters `a0`, `a1` and `a2`:

```
Manipulate[
  Plot3D[Evaluate@pdf[x, y] /. {a0 -> v0, a1 -> v1, a2 -> v2}, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4},   
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
  Mesh -> Full, Exclusions -> None],
  {{v0, 1, "a0"}, .001, 1, .001},
  {{v1, 1, "a1"}, .001, 1, .001},
  {{v2, 1, "a2"}, .001, 1, .001}]
```

Result:

[image]

**EDITED**

The discrete case:

```
DiscretePlot3D[Evaluate@pdf[x, y] /. {a0 -> 1, a1 -> 1, a2 -> 1}, 
  {x, 0, 4, .1}, {y, 0, 4, .1}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All]
```

Result:

[image]

**EDITED**

You could also plot the `ContourPlot[]` of your distribution:

```
ContourPlot[pdf[x, y] /. {a0 -> 1, a1 -> 1, a2 -> 1}, 
  {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None]
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I think that the OP means that he/she wants to _sample_ from the given distribution, that is draw a series of independent random variables that follow the given probability law.

Comment: Thanks folks for the response.I already knew these things but what I am having trouble is to get bivariate random samples (x1,y1),...(xn,yn) from the above distribution for a random sample of size n.