# RandomVariate with a custom distribution

Tags: random

I have a customized distribution and I have to draw some random number from it.

How do I use RandomVariate to draw random number from a custum distribution? My naive attempt `RandomVariate[mydist]` fails with and Mathematica throws the error:

> RandomVariate::udist: "The specification  is not a
>   random distribution recognized by the system"

My distribution is:

```
me =511000;
M = 938000000;
c = 29979200;
en=10^8;
z = 1;
ρ = 2.33;
en = 10^6;
τ[T_?NumericQ] := T/M ;
β[T_?NumericQ] := Sqrt[1 - (1/(τ[T] + 1))^2];
wm[T_?NumericQ] := (2 me β[T]^2)/(1 - β[T]^2);
Zs[T_?NumericQ] = z (1 - Exp[-((125 β[T])/z^(2/3))]);  

mydist[w_]:= 1/Σ[en] 0.307075*14/28.0855 10^6 ρ 10^-4/(β[en]^2 (w + 173)^2) (1 - (β[en]^2 (w + 173))/wm[en] + (Pi β[en] Zs[en]^2)/137 Sqrt[(w + 173)/wm[en]] (1 - (w + 173)/wm[en]))
```

$\Sigma[en]$ is the normalization, the integral of the rest between 1 and `w[en]`

Comment: How is the custom distribution defined?  Can you provide a short example?

Comment: Have a look at the answers here [How to generate a RandomVariate of a custom distribution?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13981/9490), see if they can help.

Comment: How is `w` defined?

Comment: Does the positive support for `w` range from 1 to `wm[en]` rather than `w[en]`?  If so and after fixing that, you've defined the probability density function.  To get random samples you'll need to tell *Mathematica* what the distribution is by using `ProbabilityDistribution`.  That's what the error message is telling you.