# Dot Density Plot for 3D Probability Density Function of {x, y, z}

Tags: plotting, functions, distributions

I have been calculating probability density functions for different states in the hydrogen atom, and want to plot them in 3D using a dot density plot like [this one](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PlotsOfQuantumProbabilityDensityFunctionsInTheHydrogenAtom/). However, I have not figured out how to convert my function into a list distribution that can be plotted using a density plot. Here are the three functions I've been working on.

```
probs=
{(E^(-2 Im[ArcTan[x, y]] - Re[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]]) Abs[x^2 + y^2])/(896 \[Pi]), 
(2 E^(2 Im[ArcTan[x, y]] - 2/3 Re[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]]) Abs[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] z]^2)/(45927 \[Pi]),
(3 E^(-4 Im[ArcTan[x, y]] - 1/2 Re[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]]) Abs[(x^2 + y^2) (-12 + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2])]^2)/(29360128 \[Pi])}
```

These are each for the states |211>, |32,-1>, |422>.

Comment: BTW, the three functions are normalized to their sum, so the first should be multiplied by 14, the second by 7/2, and the third by 14/9 to be normalized.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/223007/randomvariate-cannot-sample-from-a-custom-multivariate-probabilitydistribution

Comment: Is `14 probs[[1]]` just equivalent to $\frac{\left(x^2+y^2\right) e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}}{64 \pi }$ ?  In other words, is `Im[ArcTan[x, y]]` always equal to zero?