# Computational Bayesian analysis in Mathematica: Any plans to develop MCMC?

Tags: packages, simulation, probability-or-statistics

Does anyone know if there are any plans to develop an MCMC capability in Mathematica?

My reasoning for asking is that as it stands, I can't seem to find any 'out-of-the-box' functions/capabilities for doing computational Bayesian statistics. For the simple case, coding an MCMC algorithm is easy, but for hierarchical models, this is more complex, and others have implemented various efficient algorithms in BUGS, STAN or JAGS.

It seems like it would be a good addition to future versions of the software, and was just wondering whether anyone knew whether this is being considered.

Comment: I don't know whether WRI has any plans for developing MCMC. However, Phil Gregory has developed a MCMC package in Mathematica. You can download it at http://bit.ly/1tdaYhG under "Resources". BTW, I can recommend his book "Bayesian Logical Data Analysis for the Physical Sciences" in which he explains MCMC at length.

Comment: There is some hidden MCMC code in Mathematica you can use. See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212930/43522

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Update: 2/7/2019** I have just released a new version of the package: [MathematicaStan **v2.0**](https://github.com/stan-dev/MathematicaStan/tree/master)

---

I just have released a beta version of MathematicaStan, a package to interact with [CmdStan](http://mc-stan.org/interfaces/cmdstan.html).

https://github.com/vincent-picaud/MathematicaStan

**Usage example:**

```
(* Defines the working directory and loads CmdStan.m
 *)
SetDirectory["~/GitHub/MathematicaStan/Examples/Bernoulli"]
Needs["CmdStan`"]

(* Generates the Bernoulli Stan code and compiles it
 *)
stanCode="data { 
  int<lower=0> N; 
  int<lower=0,upper=1> y[N];
} 
parameters {
  real<lower=0,upper=1> theta;
} 
model {
  theta ~ beta(1,1);
  for (n in 1:N) 
    y[n] ~ bernoulli(theta);
}";
Export["bernoulli.stan",stanCode,"Text"]

(* Compile your code.
 * Caveat: this can take some time
 *)
StanCompile["bernoulli"]
```

> --- Translating Stan model to C++ code --- bin/stanc \ /home/pix/GitHub/MathematicaStan/Examples/Bernoulli/bernoulli.stan \
>   --o=/home/pix/GitHub/MathematicaStan/Examples/Bernoulli/bernoulli.hpp Model name=bernoulli_model Input
>   file=/home/pix/GitHub/MathematicaStan/Examples/Bernoulli/\
>   bernoulli.stan Output
>   file=/home/pix/GitHub/MathematicaStan/Examples/Bernoulli/\
>   bernoulli.hpp
>
> --- Linking C++ model --- g++ -I src -I stan/src -isystem stan/lib/stan_math/ -isystem \ stan/lib/stan_math/lib/eigen_3.2.8
>   -isystem \ stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.60.0 -isystem \ stan/lib/stan_math/lib/cvodes_2.8.2/include -Wall -DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG  \
>   -DBOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_TR1 -DBOOST_NO_DECLTYPE -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS \
>   -DFUSION_MAX_VECTOR_SIZE=12 -DNO_FPRINTF_OUTPUT -pipe   -lpthread  \
>   -O3 -o /home/pix/GitHub/MathematicaStan/Examples/Bernoulli/bernoulli \ src/cmdstan/main.cpp -include \
>   /home/pix/GitHub/MathematicaStan/Examples/Bernoulli/bernoulli.hpp \
>   stan/lib/stan_math/lib/cvodes_2.8.2/lib/libsundials_nvecserial.a \
>   stan/lib/stan_math/lib/cvodes_2.8.2/lib/libsundials_cvodes.a

```
(* Generates some data and saves them (RDump file)
 *)
n=1000;
y=Table[Random[BernoulliDistribution[0.2016]],{i,1,n}];

RDumpExport["bernoulli",{{"N",n},{"y",y}}];


(* Runs Stan and gets result
 *)
StanRunSample["bernoulli"]

output=StanImport["output.csv"];
```

> (Not shown because too long, CmdStan output: MCMC sampling)

```
(* You can access to output: variable names, data matrix...
 *)
StanImportHeader[output]
Dimensions[StanImportData[output]]
Take[StanImportData[output],3]
```

> {{"lp__", 1}, {"accept_stat__", 2}, {"stepsize__", 3}, {"treedepth__",
>   4}, {"n_leapfrog__", 5}, {"divergent__", 6}, {"energy__",    7},
>   {"theta", 8}}
>
> {1000, 8}
>
> {{-532.463, 0.693148, 1.47886, 1., 1., 0., 533.321, 
>     0.226882}, {-532.563, 0.974395, 1.47886, 1., 1., 0., 532.581, 
>     0.230357}, {-532.629, 0.982728, 1.47886, 1., 1., 0., 532.7, 
>     0.231909}}

```
(* Plots theta 1000 sample and associated histogram
 *)
ListLinePlot[Flatten[StanVariableColumn["theta", output]],PlotLabel->"\[Theta]"]
Histogram[Flatten[StanVariableColumn["theta", output]],PlotLabel->"\[Theta]"]
```

[image]

[image]

Feedback are welcome, especially for Windows as I only use Linux.

Comment: Could you give a small usage example within your answer?  It's not mandatory, but it would immediately give a clearer picture of what the package can do.

Comment: Sure, I tried to cut/copy one example and hope the result is not too ugly.

Answer (score 28):

For the sake of completeness let me advertise someone else's code which implements MCMC in mathematica.

[Josh Burkart](https://github.com/joshburkart) has implemented  [Mathematica Markov Chain Monte Carlo](https://github.com/joshburkart/mathematica-mcmc)
which is available on github.

His read-me reads:

## Mathematica Markov Chain Monte Carlo

Mathematica package containing a general-purpose [Markov chain Monte Carlo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain_Monte_Carlo) routine Josh Burkart  wrote. Includes various examples and documentation.

#### Features:

- Convenience wrapper for fitting models to arbitrary-dimensional data with Gaussian errors
- Handles both real-valued and discrete-valued model parameters
- Uses Metropolis algorithm with decaying exponential proposal distribution
- Progress monitor; support for auto save/resume

#### Files:

- `mcmc.m`: Package file
- `mcmc_demonst.nb`: Demonstrations and documentation

For a good Python MCMC implementation, check out [emcee](http://dan.iel.fm/emcee).

?MCMC

```
 MCMC[plogexpr, paramspec, numsteps]
```

> Perform MCMC sampling of the supplied probability distribution.
>
> 1. plogexpr should be an expression that gives the unnormalized log
>      probability for a particular choice of parameter values.
> 2. paramspec either gives the results of a previous MCMC run (w/ same
>      plogexpr--just to add on more iterations), or lists the model \
>      parameters
>      like so:
>      {{param1, ival1, spread1, domain1}, ...}
>      a) Each param should be symbolic.
>      b) ival is the initial parameter value.
>      c) spread is roughly how far to try to change the parameter each step \
>      in
>      the Markov chain. In this routine we select new parameters values based
>      on an exponential distribution of the form \
>      Exp[[CapitalDelta]param/spread]. My
>      Numerical Recipes book advises setting these spreads so that the \
>      average
>      candidate acceptance is 10-40%.
>      d) Each domain is either Reals or a list of all possible values the
>      parameter can take on (needs to be a uniform grid).
> 3. numsteps is the number of Markov chain steps to perform.

In his demonstration, the simplest example reads

```
{μ1, μ2} = {1, -2};
{σ1, σ2} = {1.2, 3.4};
plogexpr =  Log[PDF[NormalDistribution[μ1, σ1], x1] PDF[NormalDistribution[μ2, σ2], x2]];

mcmc = MCMC[plogexpr, {{x1, 0, 2, Reals}, {x2, 0, 2, Reals}}, 100000]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The result provides

```
mcmc["Properties"]
```

{"BestFitParameters", "ParameterErrors", "AverageAcceptance", 
"TimeSpent", "NumSteps", "Parameters", "ProposalSpreads", 
"ParameterDomains", "BurnFraction", "BurnEnd", "CorrelationMatrix", 
"ParameterRun", "ParametersLogPRun", "TransitionLogPRun", 
"ParameterRunPlots", "ParameterHistograms"}

For instance,

```
mcmc["ParameterHistograms"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
mcmc["ParameterRun"] // 
SmoothDensityHistogram[#, "Oversmooth", "PDF", 
ColorFunction -> ColorData["Rainbow"], Mesh -> 3, 
MeshStyle -> Directive[White, Dashed]] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The package provides  `MCMCModelFit`.

> MCMCModelFit[data, errors, model, paramspec, ivars, numsteps]
>   Perform MCMC samping of the probability distribution resulting from
>   modeling data with model, assuming Gaussian errors.

For instance

```
error = 1.5;
dattab = Table[{x, 1.3 x - 2 Sin[2 x] + 7 + 
     RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, error]]}, {x, 0, 10, .1}];
errors = Table[error, {x, 0, 10, .1}]; spr = .04;
mcmc = MCMCModelFit[dattab, errors, a x + b Sin[c x] + 
   d, {{a, 1.3, spr, Real}, {b, -2, spr, Real}, {c, 2, spr, Real}, {d,
     7, spr, Real}}, {x}, 100000];
```

produces

```
 Show[ListPlot[dattab, Joined -> False], 
 Plot[{7 + 1.3 x - 2 Sin[2 x], 
 a x + b Sin[c x] + d /. mcmc["BestFitParameters"]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Dashed, Opacity[1]], Blue}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

More generally, the author of this package gives a sequence of examples of increasing complexity  in his demonstration notebook.

It involves things like radial velocity  curves such as this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Needless to say **all the credit is his**.

### Complementary worked example

As a complement, let us consider the problem of estimating the parameters of 
a `MultinormalDistribution` from a dataset drawn from it.

```
dat = RandomVariate[
   MultinormalDistribution[{1, 0.5}, {{1, 0.95}, {0.95, 1}}], 100];
dat // Histogram3D
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Let us define the corresponding proposition PDF

```
Clear[logpdf];
logpdf[a_, b_, c_] := 
  LogLikelihood[MultinormalDistribution[{a, b}, {{1, c}, {c, 1}}], 
   dat];
```

and apply `MCMC` to estimate the corresponding most likely parameters

```
mcmc = MCMC[logpdf[a, b, c], {
    {a, 0.9, 0.3, Reals}, {b, 0.4, 0.2, Reals}, {c, 0.9, 0.2, Reals}
    }, 150000];
mcmc[{"BestFitParameters", "ParameterErrors", "ProposalSpreads", 
  "ParameterHistograms"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As expected the first two parameters are strongly correlated:

```
  mcmc["CorrelationMatrix"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which we can check by looking at the histogram of sampled points:

```
Most /@ mcmc["ParameterRun"] // 
  SmoothDensityHistogram[#, "Oversmooth", "PDF", 
    ColorFunction -> ColorData["Rainbow"], Mesh -> 5, 
    MeshStyle -> Directive[White, Dashed]] &,
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Finally see this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139147/1089) on how to use it in parallel.

Comment: Have you used this yourself? If yes, what do you think?  When you come across a good package, please do add it to http://packagedata.net/  You can log in with your SE account and your reputation gives you full access (no need to wait for moderation).

Comment: It seems to be pure Mathematica. I wonder how that affects performance.  I think LibraryLink, and in particular the features made easy to use by LTemplate, would be an excellent candidate for a high performance implementation.

Comment: The Metropolis algorithm does not parallelize trivially (although multiple parallel runs are often useful for sampling). What I meant was a full rewrite in C++. The algorithm itself is easy and quick to implement. After a quick look, I like the package design, it's made to be consistent and easy to use.

Comment: @Szabolcs would you  happen to have a simple implementation of the Metropolis algorithm?  I would like to run different draws in // and the above code is not parallel friendly (calls to Monitor etc..)? cf my question here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139133/1089

Comment: The Metropolis algorithm is a very general method. The specific implementation will depend on what set you are sampling from (numbers/vectors? states of a spin system? graphs?) and what proposal distribution you decided to use. I do not have one for numbers. I have one for the Ising model.

Comment: [Here's a quick and dirty Metropolis sampler.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38623/metropolis.nb)

Comment: I don't see any problems here ...

Comment: If I click the link, it downloads a notebook.  I am not sure what's wrong with it. Does it ask you for a login?

Comment: @Szabolcs I think Dropbox changed their public share link policy.  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38623/metropolis.nb does not exist because u/38623/ is not the method Dropbox uses anymore to share public files ?

Comment: @Szabolcs cf https://www.dropbox.com/help/16

Answer (score 14):

This [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/112739/1089) gives explicitly a (parallel) MCMC implementation in mathematica following closely this [Wolfram Demonstrations Project](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MarkovChainMonteCarloSimulationUsingTheMetropolisAlgorithm/). This basically involves only a few  lines:

```
mcmcfunComp = 
  Compile[{{s, _Real, 1}}, 
   Module[{xm, ym, proposal, xp, yp, p2, p1, 
     proposalSigma = 0.2}, {xm, ym} = s;
    xp = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[xm, proposalSigma]];
    yp = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[ym, proposalSigma]];
    p2 = pdf[xp, yp];
    p1 = pdf[xm, ym];
    proposal = p2/p1;   
    If[RandomReal[] <= proposal, {xp, yp}, {xm, ym}]],  (* THIS IS THE MCMC STEP *)
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, 
   Parallelization -> True, CompilationTarget -> "C"];

   sim = NestList[mcmcfunComp[#] &, {-4, 9}, 1000000];
```

and is quite fast!

---

### **Illustration**

As an illustration (so as to actually contribute something other than 
a link) let us implement it on a 4D PDF

Let us first define the 4D PDF as a simple sum of Gaussians

```
Clear[pdf0, pdf1, pdf2, pdf, pdfN];

pdf0 = MultinormalDistribution[{1, 0, -1, 1}, 
   1/8 {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}];
pdf1 = MultinormalDistribution[{1, 1, 0, 1}, 
   1/8 {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}];
pdf2 = MultinormalDistribution[{0, -1, 1, 0}, 
   1/8 {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}];

pdf[x_, y_, z_, t_] =
  PDF[pdf0, {x, y, z, t}] +
   1/2. PDF[pdf1, {x, y, z, t}] +
   1/4. PDF[pdf2, {x, y, z, t}];
```

Then Compile the function

```
pdfN = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {z, _Real}, {t, _Real}},
   pdf[x, y, z, t] // Evaluate, Parallelization -> True, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

Now the mcmc function itself obeys

```
mcmcfun = 
  Compile[{{s, _Real, 1}}, 
   Module[{xm, ym, zm, tm, proposal, xp, yp, zp, tp, p2, p1, 
     proposalSigma = 1}, {xm, ym, zm, tm} = s;
    xp = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[xm, proposalSigma]];
    yp = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[ym, proposalSigma]];
    zp = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[zm, proposalSigma]];
    tp = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[tm, proposalSigma]];
    p2 = pdfN[xp, yp, zp, tp];
    p1 = pdfN[xm, ym, zm, tm];
    proposal = p2/p1;
    If[RandomReal[] <= proposal, {xp, yp, zp, tp}, {xm, ym, zm, tm}]],
    CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, 
   Parallelization -> True, CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

and is indeed fast and straightforward to iterate.

```
sim = Drop[NestList[mcmcfun[#] &, {0, 0, 0, 0}, 1000000], {1, 1000}];
```

We can see by looking at different projections that it has indeed sampled the PDF

```
{{{First[#], Last[#]} & /@ sim // DensityHistogram // Image,
   {First[#], #[[2]]} & /@ sim // DensityHistogram // Image,
   {First[#], #[[3]]} & /@ sim // DensityHistogram // Image},
  {{#[[2]], #[[3]]} & /@ sim // DensityHistogram // Image,
   {#[[4]], #[[2]]} & /@ sim // DensityHistogram // Image,
   {#[[3]], #[[4]]} & /@ sim // DensityHistogram // 
    Image}} // GraphicsGrid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]