# How to catch Print and Monitor message dialog?

Tags: programming, parallelization

### Context

I am trying to parallelize a function which is verbose, and which as a consequence Mathematica does not seem to treat in parallel when doing something 
like `ParallelTable[fun[i],{i,16}]`, which does not run faster than `Table[fun[i],{i,16}]` even though the evaluation of `fun[i]` should be independent.

I think I have pinned down the problem to not being able to prevent subKernels to 
talk to the masterKernel when the function `fun` wants to `Print` and/or `Monitor` things.

### Question

Let's say I have a function

```
 fun[x_] := (Print[x]; x)
```

I would like to be able to do something like

```
 Table[fun[i] // Quiet, {i, 6}]
```

and get

{1,2,3,4,5,6}

Rather than

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

{1,2,3,4,5,6}

> I other words is there a `SuperQuiet` function which catches all outputs from it argument?

I hope this makes sense?

### Update

> What about the situation where the dialog proceeds via `Monitor` ?

Say if I have a function

```
 fun[x_] := Monitor[x,x];
```

Can I also prevent the Call to Monitor to operate so that I can efficiently  do

```
 ParallelTable[f[x],{x,10^4}];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can turn off printing, at least, by setting [`$Output`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Output.html) to `{}`, which can be done temporarily using [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html). I don't know if this will address your issue with parallel performance, because I've never seen anything like that myself. An example:

```
ClearAll[fun];
fun[x_] := (Print[x]; x);

Block[{$Output = {}},
 Table[fun[i], {i, 6}]]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} *)
```

Alternatively, since you want to just turn off the output to subkernels, you could use try

```
ParallelEvaluate[$Output = {}]
```

and just blow away the output for each one entirely. You could also have each one write to its own log file (which is usually what I do).

**EDIT** to add: In order to get rid of the `Monitor` calls, you can again use `Block`, this time to locally redefine `Monitor` to just return its first argument:

```
ClearAll[fun];
fun[x_] := Monitor[x, x];
ParallelTable[Block[{Monitor = # &}, fun[x]], {x, 10}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.02898, Null} *)
```

For comparison:

```
ParallelTable[x, {x, 10^4}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.02979, Null} *)
```

The trick of using `Block` to locally disable or redefine various system functions is one of my favorites, though it doesn't always work as you expect. It's still much less dangerous and crude than using `Unprotect` to change definitions.

Comment: Wait, are you able to have `Monitor` work at all in subkernels? It needs a front end. It might help if you could show some more of your real code....