# Generates random number from custom multivariable probability distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random

I have the following input

```
norm = Integrate[Exp[-c*x^2 - c*y^2], {x, 0, Infinity}, {y, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> c > 0];
DD[c_] = ProbabilityDistribution[1/norm Exp[-c*x^2 - c*y^2], {x, 0, Infinity}, {y, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> c > 0];
data = RandomVariate[DD[4], 15]
```

The output is

```
Out[279]= ProbabilityDistribution[(4 c E^(-\[FormalX]1^2 c - \[FormalX]2^2 c))/\[Pi], {\[FormalX]1, 0, \[Infinity]}, {\[FormalX]2, 0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> c > 0]

During evaluation of In[278]:= RandomVariate::noimp: Sampling from ProbabilityDistribution[(16 E^(-4 \[FormalX]1^2-4 \[FormalX]2^2))/\[Pi],{\[FormalX]1,0,\[Infinity]},{\[FormalX]2,0,\[Infinity]}] is not implemented. >>

Out[280]= RandomVariate[ProbabilityDistribution[(16 E^(-4 \[FormalX]1^2 - 4 \[FormalX]2^2))/\[Pi], {\[FormalX]1, 0, \[Infinity]}, {\[FormalX]2, 0, \[Infinity]}], 15]
```

Excuse me, how to fix the input to let mathematica generate random number according to the custom distribution?

Comment: In the first Integrate expression you have one set of `{}` too many around the integration variables, i.e. it should just be `Integrate[<expression>, {x, ...}, {y, ...}]`. Unfortunately, however, once you solve that problem, `RandomVariate` complains that sampling from such a distribution is not implemented. `ProbabilityDistribution` is new-ish functionality, so maybe it is still incomplete.

Comment: Try `DD = ProductDistribution[HalfNormalDistribution[Sqrt[c π]], HalfNormalDistribution[Sqrt[c π]]]`.

Comment: @J.M. seems this is a work around, is there any way to generate rather complicated custom multivariable probability function directly? I am afraid MacroB's comment, "...incomplete" is correct.

Comment: @user26143, could you edit/fix the question per marcob's comment.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2649), then.

Comment: @george2079 Thanks. Done.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. The rejection method may be useful to me, especially for more complicated PDF. I am wandering, that post was for mathematica 8. Now there are mathematica 10. Do Wolfram implement "automated random number generation from multivariate distribution"?

Comment: From my limited tests, I think simulation from custom *multivariate* distributions is still not fully supported.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RandomVariate from 2-dimensional probability distribution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2635/randomvariate-from-2-dimensional-probability-distribution)