# Generating random points on a Klein's bottle

Tags: plotting, random

There is a [neat way in Mathematica](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html) to generate random points on a sphere. Note that "randomness" is defined (somewhat not mathematically strictly) so that the points must be evenly distributed over the sphere (see more info in the linked demo):

[image]

Is there a similar (or even very different but reasonable) way of generating random points on Klien's bottle?

```
klein[u_, v_] := Module[{
   bx = 6 Cos[u] (1 + Sin[u]),
   by = 16 Sin[u],
   rad = 4 (1 - Cos[u]/2),
   X, Y, Z},
  X = If[Pi < u <= 2 Pi, bx + rad Cos[v + Pi], bx + rad Cos[u] Cos[v]];
  Y = If[Pi < u <= 2 Pi, by, by + rad Sin[u] Cos[v]];
  Z = rad Sin[v];
  {X, Y, Z}
  ]

ParametricPlot3D[klein[u, v], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

(code and image courtesy of @e.doroskevic)

Comment: @whoever cast that vote: You're kidding, surely; a close vote due to "a simple mistake"? maybe a dupe, but I'll give it the benefit of the doubt for now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's how you do from first principles.  I'd assume this is just what `RandomPoint` does internally.

compute surface incremental area associated with an area increment in parameter space:

```
del = 0.01;
da[u_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] :=
 Module[{uu, dd},
  uu = Clip[ # + del {-1, 1}, {0, 2 Pi}] & /@ {u, v}; 
  dd = Times @@ Subtract @@@ uu;
  Norm@Cross[
     klein[uu[[1, 2]], v] - klein[uu[[1, 1]], v],
     klein[u, uu[[2, 2]]] - klein[u, uu[[2, 1]]]]/dd ]
```

(The derivatives could be done analytically here but it takes a bit of hand work due to the `If` embedded in `klein` )

In principle if you normalize `da` you have a 2D PDF , unfortunately `RandomVariate` cant handle a 2d distribution [RandomVariate from 2-dimensional probability distribution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2635/2079) so we brute force it here.. ( I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do this, but it gets the job done. )

```
np = 5000;
rp = klein @@@ (RandomSample[(da @@@ #) -> #, np] &@
     RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, {50 np, 2}]);

Show[{
  ParametricPlot3D[klein[u, v], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
   Mesh -> None],
  Graphics3D[{Red, Point[rp]}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Here's an exact expression for the surface incremental area: `Norm[Cross[{6 Cos[u]^2 - 2 Sin[u] (3 + Cos[v] + 3 Sin[u]) + 2 Cos[v] (Sin[2 u] - Sin[u]) UnitStep[π - u], 16 Cos[u] - 2 (Cos[2 u] - 2 Cos[u]) Cos[v] UnitStep[π - u], 2 Sin[u] Sin[v]}, {2 (Cos[u] - 2) Sin[v] ((1 + Cos[u]) UnitStep[π - u] - 1), 2 (Cos[u] - 2) Sin[u] Sin[v] UnitStep[π - u], 2 (2 - Cos[u]) Cos[v]}]]`

Answer (score 14):

There is a function for this since *Mathematica 10.2*.

```
graphics = ParametricPlot3D[
   klein[u, v], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
   Axes -> False,
   Boxed -> False
   ];

reg = DiscretizeGraphics[graphics];
pts = RandomPoint[reg, 1000];

Show[
 graphics,
 Graphics3D[Point[pts]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, but I am not convinced that the points are uniformly distributed on the surface.

Comment: Why not? and what would convince you?

Comment: @VividD The documentation explicitly says that "`RandomPoint` will generate points uniformly in the region `reg`."

Comment: I suspect the points generated by RandomPoint will be obtained by applying uniform distribution for parameters - however, this will NOT distribute points evenly on the surface, in case of Klein's bottle. @yohbs

Comment: @C.E. It doesn't seem to me that DiscretizeGraphics generate reg that will result in even distribution of points on the surface.

Comment: Well, your suspicion is unsubstantiated. `RandomPoint` generates uniform distribution in the embedding space, not in the coordinate space. That's the sole point of having this function.

Comment: @yohbs But your embedding space may be wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I just don't get what you're saying. Can you show *why* it seems to you that it's wrong? Can you give any demonstration that it is not uniform?  Unless you do so, there's really no point in debating this.

Comment: I am asking the question, I should expect you to give me the proof of correctness, not vice versa. @yohbs

Comment: Well, that's both rude, disrespectful and ungrateful. You asked a question showing zero effort, got an answer saying that what you're looking for is a built in function, expressed unsubstantiated doubts about the implementation of this function, again showing zero effort in supporting your claim nor gratitude for @C.E. For taking the time to answer you, and now you expect us to provide a proof of correctness? Why on earth do you think that someone will do that for you?

Comment: No, @yohbs the basics of science is to raise doubts and ask for proofs.

Comment: You can ask as many questions and raise as many doubts as you want. The basics of etiquette is to show some effort if you want other people to do stuff for you.

Comment: Validating the actually uniformity of the `RandomPoint` distribution should be a new question (The question isn't really specific to the Klein bottle is it?).  Of course if you pose the question you should show some thought as to how to approach it.

Comment: I want to see the algorithm and proof-of-correctness as much as anybody, but this is Mathematica Stack Exchange, not Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I think the more general question might be a better fit there, not here - I would only expect the name of a built-in function here unless the question was specifically about implementation details.

Comment: I don't see Mathematica Stack Exchange as "somebody doing work for someone else" at all but as a free intellectual playground where we can together ask and answer and discuss, and be rewarded by the knowledge. But, @yohbs obviously does not share my view, that is his right too, what can I do.

Comment: @VividD RandomPoint does sample uniformly over a region. In fact here's a blog post about RandomPoint where in the first paragraph the author talks about how sampling over the parameters of a sphere does not give a uniform sample in this sense. http://blog.wolfram.com/2015/11/13/new-in-the-wolfram-language-randompoints/

Comment: @ChipHurst Yes, an excellent link, thanks.